# How can I set an environment variable in node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

How can I set an environment variable in node.js?

I would prefer not to rely on anything platform specific, such as running export or cmd.exe's set.

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You can set your environment variables in `process.env`:

```
process.env['VARIABLE'] = 'value';
```

*-OR-*

```
process.env.VARIABLE = 'value';
```

Node should take care of the platform specifics.

Comment: I don't think you need to do `var process = require('process')`, process is a global variable present.

Comment: Note, though, that this will only set the variable within your node process and any child processes it calls; it will not, for example, leave the variable set in the shell when the node process exits (changing the environment of a parent process is very system-dependent and not always even possible).

Comment: anyone offer an opinion on process.env.variable vs global.variable?

Comment: Why not use `process.env.VARIABLE`?

Comment: `process.env.VARIABLE` is okay if the variable name is a known constant, while `process.env['VARIABLE']` works in any case; original question did not specify enough detail, so the more versatile example seemed better suited.

Comment: @ebohlman Is it possible to leave the variable set in the shell after the node process finishes?

Comment: @BillMorris no, it is not possible for any process to modify its parent's environment

Comment: You should be able to write to the current users .profile or .bashrc then source it, if you do want to manipulate the parent environment

Comment: @EricUldall no, .profile and .bashrc are loaded when a shell starts; they will not be automatically re-executed by an already running shell, and then again the parent process might not be a shell at all.

Comment: @lanzz, that is correct. I think you misinterpreted my solution though.
`source $(node-exec); #adds export to profile and prints filename to stdout`

Comment: can we use this variable while executing some of our python scripts without passing it as a command line argument?

Comment: @user9645113 yes, that's exactly how environment variables work. You can access them in your scripts via the `os.environ` dictionary

Comment: yeah but i am unable to do so getting error defined this in my node-app `process.env.data = "data-env";` and now i am unable to access this variable in python script using this `print(os.environ["data"])` can you tell me what's going wrong with this @lanzz?

Comment: @user9645113 you should open a new question with a full description of your circumstances. Comments aren't the right venue for solving your problem

Comment: By some reason this approach doesn't work and throws an error:
`ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference.`

What might be wrong?

Comment: This doesn't create an environment variable...

Comment: @GuyNesher what does it do then?

Comment: @lanzz from a short experiment, it does nothing really - it stores the values in memory, so in the current process/child processes its able to access the value, but it won't be available for external applications/processes. 

This kinda of makes sense and is inline with previous comments. I'm just surprised this is upvoted.

Comment: You cannot affect the environment of other existing processes. If the current process were to spawn a _new_ process though, that new process _will_ have these values in its new environment (unless you explicitly specify a hand-crafted new environment, e.g. using `{env: explicit_environment}` options for `child_process.exec()`). This is how environment variables work in principle, it's not Node-specific.

Answer (score 3):

First you should install this package :- 
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv [`npm install dotenv`]

Then you need to create a .env file in your project's root directory, and there you can add variables like below:-

```
NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
```

Now you can easily access these variables in your code like below:-

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

It worked for me, hopefully that helps.

Comment: How secure is the .env file used by dotenv? If the secrets are plain text within environment strings in the .env file, is that any more secure than having them as plain text in your node code? Which is clearly a no-no?

Comment: The OP is asking how to set an environment variable from within a nodejs process/script, and not to read from a .env file and use it during runtime.

Comment: "set an environment variable in node.js" does not necessarily mean "from within node.js", but could mean "in the ecosystem of node.js". I found this on a search for the latter, and this is the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

**node v14.2.0**
To set env variable first create a file name config.env in your project home directory and then write all the variables you need, for example

config.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3000
DATABASE=mongodb+srv://lord:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-eeev8.mongodb.net/tour-guide?retryWrites=true&w=majority
DATABASE_LOCAL=mongodb://localhost:27017/tours-test
DATABASE_PASSWORD=UDJUKXJSSJPWMxw
```

now install dotenv from npm, dotenv will offload your work

```
npm i dotenv
```

now in your server starter script, in my case it is server.js use doenv to load env variables.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app'); // must be after loading env vars using dotenv

//starting server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

I am using express, all my express code in app.js, writing here for your reference

```
const express = require('express');
const tourRouter = require('./route/tourRouter');
const userRouter = require('./route/userRouter');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  console.log('mode development');
}
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

now start your server using the console, I am using **nodemon**, you can install it from npm;

```
nodemon server.js
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to set an environment variable from within a nodejs process/script, and not to read from a .env file and use it during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

### Well what I do is I first install dotenv package from npm

`npm install dotenv`

### Then I import it in my file.

`require('dotenv').config();`

### Then You are good to go. :)

You can read variables by using:

`console.log(process.env.MY_VARIABLE);`

While you can ***SET*** a Variable by using:

`process.env.MY_OTHER_VARIABLE = 'helloworld`;

Comment: Please do not use headers in your reply.

Comment: The OP is asking how to set an environment variable from within a nodejs process/script, and not to read from a .env file and use it during runtime.