# How to set environment variables from within package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

How to set some environment variables from within `package.json` to be used with `npm start` like commands?

Here's what I currently have in my `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "help": "tagove help",
    "start": "tagove start"
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to set environment variables (like `NODE_ENV`) in the start script while still being able to start the app with just one command, `npm start`.

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Answer (score 749, accepted):

Set the environment variable in the script command:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec"
},
...
```

Then use `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your app.

Note: This is for *Mac & Linux only*. For Windows refer to the comments.

Comment: Has some one figured out an alternate for windows..?

Comment: @infinity [Better npm run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run) solves cross-platform compatibility issues. Its config is somewhat clumsy though.

Comment: @infinity use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and is very easy to use.

Comment: @infinity use `set NODE_ENV=test&& mocha --reporter spec` - there is no space between the test and && on purpose.

Comment: Thanks @JamiePenney. I had to remove the space before && to get it to work. Why is that? `set NODE_ENV=development&& (nexttask)

Comment: @TetraDev can't remember sorry, I think it was including the space in the set call?

Comment: cross-env worked in seconds for me. Consider only adding it with --save-dev if you just need it for npm test

Comment: Doesn't work for `npm run-script build`. Error thrown *'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`*

Comment: `"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec"` will not work on Windows systems.

Comment: @TetraDev I think you would end up with `NODE_ENV` set to 'test ' (note the space). No space is a way to avoid that in case you don't want to (or can't) use quotes.

Comment: If you do use cross-env there is no need to include '&&'. Example: `cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start`

Comment: @infinity @jamie-penney `env NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec` will use the declared environment variable in a natively cross platform fashion, but the key is it is used by npm in an ad hoc and one-time fashion, just for the npm script execution.  (It's not set or exported for future reference.)  As long as you're running your command from the npm script, there's no issue.  Also, the "&&" must be removed when doing it this way.

Comment: if you want to use the env var inside the script itself you need to prepend $, for example if you run `mode=prod npm run print` and you have a script in your package.json called print `"print": "echo environment '$mode'"` it will print `environment 'prod'`

Comment: @infinity  Multiple environment variables can be set on windows like so:    "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "set:env:this:way": "env FIRST=one env SECOND=two node index.js"
  },

Comment: `Note: env ensures that it works across platforms.` How? `env` is not a valid command on Windows.

Comment: What is the `env` you refer to here? Can you post a link?

Comment: on windows it works like this: scripts: { "testing": "cypress open --env CYPRESS_CypressBaseUrl=localhost:3000"} ( here: npm  > 6, node > 13 )

Comment: I want to use a .env file so that I have all of those important details in a single spot, and so I can run the server from the terminal, or from docker, or docker-compose or whatever. Not finding this very helpful...

Comment: As a Windows users (in 2021), you can use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to run my Node projects locally. This video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOXatmtBb88](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOXatmtBb88) explains how to setup VSCode to use the WSL command line instead of PowerShell. This allows you to run projects such as [https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-ssr-kit](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-ssr-kit) from Windows. If you look at the package.json script in this example project you will see it sets environment variables within the node commands.

Comment: As what @w.PatrickGale has suggested, to run WSL in vscode. I believe it might be possible to simply run the `bash` command in cmd to change to a Linux environment too.

Comment: env-cmd is better

Comment: elegant way to have a prod build go through a dev config so I can easily host solid demos locally without having to manually set environment variables. Adding this to a custom NPM script provided a way to do this with one command without significantly changing anything else.

Comment: Btw to not have to lose your mind over such a dumb bug, if you set the NODE_ENV like that:
```bash
set NODE_ENV=development && ts-node --transpile-only src/index.ts
```

This will actually include a white space as well as the end of the value, fix it by removing the white space:

```bash
set NODE_ENV=development&& ts-node --transpile-only src/index.ts
```

Wasted half an hour debugging this dumb bug lol

Answer (score 382):

Just use NPM package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). Super easy. Works on Windows, Linux, and all environments. Notice that you don't use && to move to the next task. You just set the env and then start the next task. Credit to [@mikekidder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2130585/mikekidder) for the suggestion in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js#comment57929242_27090755) here.

From documentation:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production OTHERFLAG=myValue webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

Notice that if you want to set multiple global vars, you just state them in succession, followed by your command to be executed.

Ultimately, the command that is executed (using spawn) is:

```
webpack --config build/webpack.config.js
```

The `NODE_ENV` environment variable will be set by cross-env

Comment: Triple backslashes can be used to escape required quotes: `"test": "cross-env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"}' mocha"`

Comment: Can someone finally help me decide if I should use `env` or `cross-env`? On one hand, env doesn't require me to install anything and on the other hand `cross-env` is more popular. Can someone please confirm if `env` works on all platforms?

Comment: @Rishav `env` does not work as-is on all platforms, hence the reason for `cross-env` to exist. Just use `cross-env` and be done with it.

Comment: Also, may be used cross-env-shell instead of cross-env. You can read about it here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#cross-env-vs-cross-env-shell

Comment: It doesn't work for the `install` script though, I am struggling with Playwright to set PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1 before running the install of playwright package

Comment: This seems to work better for install, based on @Teemuk answer: `"preinstall": "export PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1 || set PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1"`
The difficulty is that during install, you have no package, and you cannot have an inline script, so you have to find a pure shell solution that works for Windows, in the `preinstall` command.

Comment: This package is now deprecated. [env-cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201206/542251) is the obvious replacement

Answer (score 89):

Because I often find myself working with multiple environment variables, I find it useful to keep them in a separate `.env` file (make sure to ignore this from your source control). Then (in Linux) prepend `export $(cat .env | xargs) &&`  in your script command before starting your app.

Example `.env` file:

```
VAR_A=Hello World
VAR_B=format the .env file like this with new vars separated by a line break
```

Example `index.js`:

```js
console.log('Test', process.env.VAR_A, process.env.VAR_B);
```

Example `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",

    "env-linux": "export $(cat .env | xargs) && env",
    "start-linux": "export $(cat .env | xargs) && npm start",

    "env-windows": "(for /F \"tokens=*\" %i in (.env) do set %i)",
    "start-windows": "(for /F \"tokens=*\" %i in (.env) do set %i) && npm start",

  }
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to set the environment variables by calling a script from a script -- like `"start-windows": "npm run env-windows && npm start"` -- so there is some redundancy in the scripts.

For a test you can see the env variables by running `npm run env-linux` or `npm run env-windows`, and test that they make it into your app by running `npm run start-linux` or `npm run start-windows`.

Comment: Very good, it almost did the job for me!

I'd like to add a few comments:

- You cannot have empty lines in your .env file
- Comments in your .env file will break your script
- If multiple scripts use the same .env file, you will have to repeat that
- I had to remove the space before `&&` for it to work
- If you have multiple .env files, it may be a little harder to maintain

Your answer inspired me to prepare this suggestion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json/61052350#61052350

Comment: I'm not following the env-windows script.  The cmd shell won't recognize export nor the xargs.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @FelipeNMoura and @DerekGreer . Not sure why I thought `export $(cat .env | xargs) && set` worked on Windows. I re-did the windows script, tested it out, and made edits to my answer.

Comment: Use `export $(cat .env | xargs)&&` instead of  `export $(cat .env | xargs) &&` to avoid an extra whitespace in the env variables. These spaces won't show up in console.log and can mess up the code(as it did mine)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 83):

I just wanted to add my two cents here for future Node-explorers. On my Ubuntu 14.04 the `NODE_ENV=test` didn't work, I had to use `export NODE_ENV=test` after which `NODE_ENV=test` started working too, weird.

On Windows as have been said you have to use `set NODE_ENV=test` but for a cross-platform solution the cross-env library didn't seem to do the trick and do you really need a library to do this:

```js
export NODE_ENV=test || set NODE_ENV=test&& yadda yadda
```

The vertical bars are needed as otherwise Windows would crash on the unrecognized `export NODE_ENV` command. I don't know about the trailing space, but just to be sure I removed them too.

Comment: Did you use `&&`? `NODE_ENV=test yadda` means "run `yadda`, setting `NODE_ENV` within `yadda`'s environment variables. `NODE_ENV=test && yadda` means "set `NODE_ENV` within the local environment, but don't export it, then run `yadda`." `NODE_ENV=test yadda` is the preferred approach.

Comment: Sorry that haven't checked my stackoverflow account in a while. But basically silly Windows didn't work using `NODE_ENV=test && npm run test` or something similar. I made a better solution using `process.env["NODE_ENV"] = "testing";` inside my testhelper.js file.

Comment: @TeemuK just to add my two cents too, when you run your command with `&&` you lost your environment variables, setting environment variables without export works on the current command only (which is nothing). to run the command with the env variable without exporting u do:  `NODE_ENV=test npm run test`. Finally the reason it worked after you exported, is because ur variable is now available (exported) in the session, your NODE_ENV without export wasnt doing anything.

Comment: If you want to set multiple envs at once remember that logic operators in both cmd and bash are strictly from left to right, so chains are easily achievable, and If you want to have clean output after execiting such cross env on windows you can do it like so:

`export NODE_ENV=0 2>nul || set NODE_ENV=0 && export TRIAL_MODE=1 2>nul || set TRIAL_MODE=1 && echo "$NODE_ENV $TRIAL_MODE %NODE_ENV %TRIAL_MODE"`

Please remember that on Windows cmd env are available after executing statement, so they are not available in one line solutions.

Answer (score 43):

Try this on Windows by replacing `YOURENV`:

```json
  {
    ...
     "scripts": {
       "help": "set NODE_ENV=YOURENV && tagove help",
       "start": "set NODE_ENV=YOURENV && tagove start"
     }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I had to remove the space before &&.

Comment: @KennethSolberg's comment was the final touch that made it work for me (Windows only)

Comment: I too had the space issue. When logging string length I could tell the space is added. I tried escaped quotes - and they were actually stored in the envar. I tried other delimiters to no avail. Removing the space or trimming the value, which feels wrong to me, were the only ways around this issue.

Comment: THE SPACE!!! Man, it literally worked!

Comment: env-cmd package get the .env automatically

Comment: On windows, I had to use single & instead of double && and it worked for me. e.g. set NODE_ENV=YOURENV & tagove help

Answer (score 20):

@luke's answer was almost the one I needed! Thanks.

As the selected answer is very straightforward (and correct), but old, I would like to offer an alternative for importing variables from a .env separate file when running your scripts and fixing some limitations to Luke's answer.
Try this:

::: .env file :::

```
# This way, you CAN use comments in your .env files
NODE_PATH="src/"

# You can also have extra/empty lines in it
SASS_PATH="node_modules:src/styles"
```

Then, in your package json, you will create a script that will set the variables and run it before the scripts you need them:

::: package.json :::

```
scripts: {
  "set-env": "export $(cat .env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs)",
  "storybook": "npm run set-env && start-storybook -s public"
}
```

### Some observations:

- The regular expression in the grep'ed cat command will clear the comments and empty lines.
- The `&&` don't need to be *"glued"* to `npm run set-env`, as it would be required if you were setting the variables in the same command.
- If you are using yarn, you may see a warning, you can either change it to `yarn set-env` or use `npm run set-env --scripts-prepend-node-path &&` instead.

### Different environments

Another advantage when using it is that you can have different environment variables.

```
scripts: {
  "set-env:production": "export $(cat .production.env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs)",
  "set-env:development": "export $(cat .env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs)",
}
```

> Please, remember not to add .env files to your git repository when you have keys, passwords or sensitive/personal data in them!

Comment: The `export $(cat .env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs) ` command works only if it is in the same script as my main script. This would work: `export $(cat .env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs) && docker exec -it ${MY_VARIABLE}_wp sh`. But this won't: `npm run set-env && docker exec -it ${MY_VARIABLE}_wp sh`.

Comment: I couldn't able to run the grep command above. So I used egrep.  
`export $(cat .env | egrep '^[^#]' | xargs)`

Answer (score 17):

For a larger set of environment variables or when you want to reuse them you can use [`env-cmd`](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd).

As a plus, the `.env` file would also work with [direnv](https://direnv.net/).

`./.env` file:

```
# This is a comment
ENV1=THANKS
ENV2=FOR ALL
ENV3=THE FISH
```

`./package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd mocha -R spec"
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you use ENV1 in the script?

Comment: The usual `process.env.ENV1`

Comment: but, inside the package.json? i had read that is impossible(?)

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you do that?

Comment: maybe is a silly aproach, but I had update the macOs Catalina and now the command mongodb is not working, so I need to specify the data/folder `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`. I want to run something like `npm mongodb` and that will get the environment variable dbpath and run the mondodb just as always... and.. i want to share it with other members.

Answer (score 17):

#### UPDATE: This solution may break in npm v7 due to [npm RFC 21](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md)

#### CAVEAT: no idea if this works with `yarn`

---

npm (and yarn) passes *a lot* of data from package.json into scripts as environment variables.  Use `npm run env` to see them all.  This is documented in https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#environment and is not only for "lifecycle" scripts like `prepublish` but also any script executed by `npm run`.

You can access these inside code (e.g. `process.env.npm_package_config_port` in JS) but they're already available to the shell running the scripts so you can also access them as `$npm_...` expansions in the "scripts" (unix syntax, might not work on windows?).

The ["config" section](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#config) seems intended for this use:

```json
  "name": "myproject",
  ...
  "config": {
    "port": "8010"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js $npm_package_config_port",
    "test": "wait-on http://localhost:$npm_package_config_port/ && node test.js http://localhost:$npm_package_config_port/"
  }
```

An important quality of these "config" fields is that *users can override them without modifying package.json*!

```
$ npm run start

> myproject@0.0.0 start /home/cben/mydir
> node server.js $npm_package_config_port

Serving on localhost:8010

$ npm config set myproject:port 8020
$ git diff package.json  # no change!
$ cat ~/.npmrc
myproject:port=8020

$ npm run start

> myproject@0.0.0 start /home/cben/mydir
> node server.js $npm_package_config_port

Serving on localhost:8020
```

See [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) and [yarn config](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/config/) docs.
It appears that yarn reads `~/.npmrc` so `npm config set` affects both, but `yarn config set` writes to `~/.yarnrc`, so only yarn will see it :-(

Comment: Note that [`$npm_package_*` variables are no longer automatically placed in the environment since NPM v7](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/305), so this will probably break.

Answer (score 15):

When the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to 'production' all devDependencies in your `package.json` file will be completely ignored when running npm install. You can also enforce this with a `--production` flag:

```
npm install --production
```

For setting `NODE_ENV` you can use any of these methods

**method 1**: set `NODE_ENV` for all node apps

`Windows` :

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

`Linux, macOS or other unix` based system :

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

This sets NODE_ENV for current bash session thus any apps started after this statement will have NODE_ENV set to production.

**method 2**: set `NODE_ENV` for current app

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

This will set `NODE_ENV` for the current app only. This helps when we want to test our apps on different environments.

**method 3**: create `.env` file and use it

This uses the idea explained here. Refer this post for more detailed explanation.

Basically, you create a .env file and run some bash scripts to set them on the environment.

To avoid writing a bash script, the env-cmd package can be used to load the environment variables defined in the .env file.

```
env-cmd .env node app.js
```

**method 4**: Use `cross-env package`

This package allows environment variables to be set in one way for every platform.

After installing it with npm, you can just add it to your deployment script in package.json as follows:

```
"build:deploy": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

Answer (score 14):

This will work in **Windows console**:

```
"scripts": {
  "setAndStart": "set TMP=test&& node index.js",
  "otherScriptCmd": "echo %TMP%"
}
```

`npm run aaa`

output:
`test`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238291/1844247) for details.

Comment: Should be `set TMP=test&& npm run bbb`. The space before `&&` will also cound as part of then `NODE_ENV` string

Comment: @FisNaN Shouldn't be the case if you surround it with quotes `"`.

Comment: This work without the space before `&&`. So `"scripts": {
  "aaa": "set TMP=test&& npm run bbb",
  "bbb": "echo %TMP%"
}`

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett I can't check this right now, feel free to edit the answer if you're sure it works in the Windows console.

Answer (score 11):

For single environment variable

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node server.js"
 }
```

For multiple environment variables

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& set PORT=8000&& node server.js"
 }
```

Comment: Answers the question/works, but probably not the best. You may end up including API keys etc in your version control repo, assuming you're including your package.json in your repo.

Answer (score 10):

suddenly i found that actionhero is using following code, that solved my problem by just passing `--NODE_ENV=production` in start script command option.

```js
if(argv['NODE_ENV'] != null){
  api.env = argv['NODE_ENV'];
} else if(process.env.NODE_ENV != null){
  api.env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
}
```

i would really appreciate to accept answer of someone else who know more better way to set environment variables in package.json or init script or something like, where app bootstrapped by someone else.

Answer (score 10):

use git bash in windows. Git Bash processes commands differently than cmd.

*Most Windows command prompts will choke when you set environment variables with NODE_ENV=production like that. (The exception is Bash on Windows, which uses native Bash.) Similarly, there's a difference in how windows and POSIX commands utilize environment variables. With POSIX, you use: $ENV_VAR and on windows you use %ENV_VAR%.* - cross-env doc

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "help": "tagove help",
    "start": "env NODE_ENV=production tagove start"
  }
  ...
}
```

use dotenv package to declare the env variables

Answer (score 8):

Running a node.js script from package.json with multiple environment variables:

1. package.json file:

```js
    "scripts": {
        "do-nothing": "set NODE_ENV=prod4 && set LOCAL_RUN=true && node ./x.js",
 },
```

x.js file can be as:

```js
let env     = process.env.NODE_ENV;
let isLocal = process.env.LOCAL_RUN;

console.log("ENV"    , env);
console.log("isLocal", isLocal);
```

Answer (score 6):

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ENV NODE_ENV=production someapp --options"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most elegant and portable solution:
`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "export NODE_PRESERVE_SYMLINKS_MAIN=1 && vue-cli-service serve"
    },
```

Under `windows` create `export.cmd` and put it somewhere to your `%PATH%`:

```
@echo off

set %*
```

Comment: This is simple, but quite nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

If you:

- Are currently using Windows;
- Have git bash installed;
- Don't want to use `set ENV` in your package.json which makes it only runnable for Windows dev machines;

Then you can set the script shell of node from cmd to git bash and write linux-style env setting statements in `package.json` for it to work on both Windows/Linux/Mac.

```
$ npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not directly answering the question I´d like to share an idea on top of the other answers. From what I got each of these would offer some level of complexity to achieve cross platform independency.

On my scenario all I wanted, originally, to set a variable to control whether or not to secure the server with JWT authentication (for development purposes)

After reading the answers I decided simply to create 2 different files, with authentication turned on and off respectively.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --debug  index_auth.js",
    "devna": "nodemon --debug  index_no_auth.js",
  }
```

The files are simply wrappers that call the original index.js file (which I renamed to `appbootstrapper.js`):

```js
//index_no_auth.js authentication turned off
const bootstrapper = require('./appbootstrapper');
bootstrapper(false);

//index_auth.js authentication turned on
const bootstrapper = require('./appbootstrapper');
bootstrapper(true);

class AppBootStrapper {

    init(useauth) {
        //real initialization
    }
}
```

Perhaps this can help someone else

Answer (score 1):

You should not set ENV variables in `package.json`. actionhero uses `NODE_ENV` to allow you to change configuration options which are loaded from the files in `./config`.  Check out the [redis config file](https://github.com/evantahler/actionhero/blob/master/config/redis.js), and see how NODE_ENV is uses to change database options in `NODE_ENV=test`

If you want to use other ENV variables to set things (perhaps the HTTP port), you still don't need to change anything in `package.json`.  For example, if you set `PORT=1234` in ENV and want to use that as the HTTP port in `NODE_ENV=production`, just reference that in the relevant config file, IE:

```
# in config/servers/web.js
exports.production = { 
  servers: {
    web: function(api){
      return {
       port: process.env.PORT
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: great. i think you didn't read my question.. my problem is how to set NODE_ENV not what is use of it.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative way to explain this would be that NODE_ENV (and other environment variables) are part of the environment (hence the name).  They are usually properties of the server you are running the application on rather than your application.  You can set them manually via the command you exec, ie: `NODE_ENV=test npm start` or have them set by the shell

Comment: I disagree. using a ./config for every environment confines you to using static environments when you deploy your app. This is an outdated philosophy that will not allow you to spin up new types of environments when needed. I.E. for every new environment you want, you will have to add a .config. Setting environment variables at runtime can be a superior option when your tech stack requires more flexibility. I think your ./config would be good for setting up "types" of environments, but your app would be more flexible if you could define things like dsn strings and api endpoints at runtime.

Comment: @JesseGreathouse - I have a node.js application and I need to set the environment variables at runtime - what file would I set them in?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to use of [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) as documented above, for setting a few environment variables within a `package.json` 'run script', if your script involves running NodeJS, then you can set Node to pre-require `dotenv/config`:

```js
{
  scripts: {
    "eg:js": "node -r dotenv/config your-script.js",
    "eg:ts": "ts-node -r dotenv/config your-script.ts",
    "test":  "ts-node -r dotenv/config -C 'console.log(process.env.PATH)'",
  }
}
```

This will cause your node interpreter to require `dotenv/config`, which will itself read the `.env` file in the present working directory from which node was called.

The `.env` format is lax or liberal:

```bash
# Comments are permitted
FOO=123
BAR=${FOO}
BAZ=Basingstoke Round About

#Blank lines are no problem
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** In order to set multiple environment variable, script should goes like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& set MONGO_USER=your_DB_USER_NAME&& set MONGO_PASSWORD=DB_PASSWORD&& set MONGO_DEFAULT_DATABASE=DB_NAME&& node app.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Using crossenv is probably your best bet as already answered here.

You might want to try using the new Bun.sh for complex scripts. I've been able to clean up my package.json scripts a lot and I can even use typescript scripts. It's great.

https://bun.sh/docs/cli/run

bun run index.js

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "bun run src/scripts/index.ts",
  "dev": "bun run --watch src/scripts/index.ts",
  "simple": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production start "
},
```