# Add react middleware when not in production

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-middleware

The question is simple,

How I can add a react or redux middle-ware (like Logger) when not in production.

I don't want users be able to see the logging info in the console tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have 2 middlewares, `logger` and `thunk` and you want to add `logger`  when you are not in `production`, you can do that using following code:

```
const middleware = [thunk];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(logger);
}
```

And you can set `NODE_ENV` to `production` using following code:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

Or using PowerShell:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

Set within `package.json` (*you need to install [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), more info right here: [How to set Environment variables from within package.json [Node.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25112510/3367974)*):

```
"scripts": {    
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no a Redux way to do this. It is up to you to implement this logic. You may use the `window.location.origin` to get an idea of where you app runs. If it runs on localhost or your staging environment then you should not add the logger. Of course if you server-side render you have to check if `window` is available. If not I guess is fine to add the logger. Check out how it is done in redux-devtools https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/npm-package/developmentOnly.js#L7