# Run npm script with environment variable from package.json

Tags: environment-variables, package.json, npm-scripts

I am using a specific task runner to execute my node scripts called Yoshi. I want to run a script from `package.json`, for example, `yoshi test` but with a **custom environment variable** (for example *special_variable*):

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "yoshi start", 
    "test":  "special_variable=value yoshi test // this case"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Environment variables from within package.json \[Node.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js)

Comment: They are explicitly speaking about the NODE_ENV variable and not a custom one...

Comment: The solution in the linked answer equally applies to custom variables too.  E.g. `FOO=bar` - I fail to see what makes your variable any more _special_ than `NODE_ENV`? If you're using a Bash shell you can check this by using [`printenv`](https://ss64.com/bash/printenv.html) in an _npm-script_. For instance: `"list-env-vars" : "FOO=bar printenv"`,  then run `npm run list-env-vars` and you'll see `FOO=bar` listed as an env variable.

Comment: Weird, I tried it before and it didn't work, but now, looks like you are right. I'm closing this one.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I can pass an environment variable using the **`ENV`** prefix in my `npm-script` like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "yoshi start", 
    "test":  "ENV special_variable=value yoshi test"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create `.env` file and add your variables there.