# why can't i set environment value in package.json script

Tags: javascript, command, package.json

i really feel confused when i want to set some environment variable in one project's package.json scripts.i tried script like:

```
"start": "cp -f ./src... && NODE_ENV=dev wepy build --watch"
```

it works right and i get `dev` of `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

But why the following commands i firstly wrote can't set environment variable.and i get `undefined` of `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

```
"start": "cp -f ./src... && NODE_ENV=dev && wepy build --watch"
```

or

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=dev && cp -f ./src... && wepy build --watch"
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you elaborate what problem you are having? If the first way works, why not just use it? The use of `&&` also seems to depend on the OS you're using if you look at the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090755/7595777). Maybe this helps to specify your problem? 
Also please check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on how to format code blocks.

Comment: @luke-codewalker Thanks for your advice~I am a newbie for using stackoverflow.