# Can I choose between develop config file and production config file in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I'm having a problem. I need to use some configs file when I'm working in a develop environment and other when I'm working in Production environment.

I'd like to compile using something like this:

tsc --production=true

And then in my code:

```
 if(process.argv.split(2)==true)
     //USE CONFIG FILE PRODUCTION
 else
     //USE CONFIG FILE DEVELOP
```

Comment: When you say config file, do you mean your `tsconfig.json`? If that's the case, then you can write two separate files, like `tsconfig.dev.json` and `tsconfig.prod.json`, and then use the `--project` option to specify which one to use, depending on whether you're building for dev or production.

Comment: @ethan.roday Thanks you but I need to use a develop.properties and a production.properties with the conection to the database for example. So, when I run: tsc --productio=true my program has to use the production database

Comment: Ah okay. This is not really something that `tsc` does. Are you using a package manager such as `npm` or a bundler like Webpack? Those would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ahh.. great! Yes I don't know too much about this. I'm using firebase cloudfunctions and I run: "npm run build". Howerver, in the package.json there is the following configuration:  "scripts": { "build": "tsc" }

Comment: Perfect! In that case, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js

Comment: I would definitely recommend using `cross-env`, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Then, in your actual code, you can say `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") { ... } else { ... }`.