# How to use custom env(.env.production.abc) file in npm script

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment, package.json, dotenv

I am using same code for multiple project, based on environment file value it give different functionality to project.

I have added:

```
"scripts":{
  "abc": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js"
  "xyz": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js"
}
```

So I want to do like if i run `npm run abc` it should take `.env.production.abc` and if I run command `npm run xyz` it should take `.env.production.xyz`.

Is it possible?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js

Comment: @PranavRamachandran I don't want include environment variables in command I want to add env files in command because I have multiple environment variables and i don't want to pass in command. I want pass only env file.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv this might helpful for you

Comment: if you are using webpack, you need to do it by define plugin in webpack config

Answer (score 0):

try the following changes. Install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in your project

```
"scripts":{
  "abc": "npm-run-all -p watch-css -r dotenv/config start.js dotenv_config_path=/path/to/abc/env"
  "xyz": "npm-run-all -p watch-css -r dotenv/config start.js dotenv_config_path=/path/to/xyz/env"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DefinePlugin in your webpack configuration.

In your **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    .......
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
    .......
}
```

Now you have `NODE_ENV` variable here.

you need to create same file name with respect to the value you are providing in `NODE_ENV`.

**example:**

in your **package.json**

```
"abc": "NODE_ENV=staging npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js"
"xyz": "NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js"
```

Now you should have

`staging.js` and `production.js` file present.

Comment: I know how to make staging and Production ENV file and it how to use that apply.
Maybe you don't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

This module does that: [Custom env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-env)

Answer (score -1):

We can use npm packages like `env-cmd` or `react-app-env` which can help us to handle these type of scenarios.