# nextjs - next build with NODE_ENV=development

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'd like to build my `nextjs` project as **development** mode.

and I tried like it

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development & next build",
    "build:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production & next build",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development & next start",
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production & next start"
  }
  ...
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = withSass({
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "devServerURL": "prodServerURL"
  }
});
```

but I couldn't achieve what I want.

so, I tried with some change.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development & next start",
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production & next start"
  }
```

but it also doesn't work.

How can I build the `next` with development mode?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: According to https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3605, it's not possible in the moment.

Comment: In the contrary, it seems that you cannot set NODE_ENV = production within next dev command

Comment: Next.js provides the environment you are working on based on how you start it. Note that if you use next dev command it will start the service in development mode. If you next build && next start it will produce a production build. To achieve what you are trying to do use .env.development and .env.production. Those two files will be loaded based on the environment you started. You can use the same variable (SERVER_URL=server.depending.on.environment) and recall it with process.env.SERVER_URL in your code.

Comment: Wontfixed: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4022#issuecomment-374010365 ... I'm just gonna create a secondary `NODE_ENV_OVERRIDE` and check for that I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE 2022-11-23:

See [how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json).

In short:
`"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development next start"`

You might need [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) *(on Windows ? I don't know)*:
`"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development next start"`

More specific documentation is now available *(and maybe requirements also have changed, or maybe not)*:

[environment-variable-load-order](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order):

> ... Note: The allowed values for NODE_ENV are production, development and test.

[non-standard-node-env](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env):

> ... only permitting three (3) values:
>
> - production: When your application is built with next build
> - development: When your application is ran with next dev
> - test: When your application is being tested (e.g. jest)

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

See [issue #9123, (Oct 18, 2019)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9123#issuecomment-543784086)  :

> NODE_ENV is a reserved environment variable that cannot be changed.
> The only valid values are production, development, and test.
>
> If you need your app behavior to change in different production
> environments, please use a different variable like APP_ENV.

And [issues #17032 (Sep 12, 2020)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17032#issuecomment-691491353):

> `process.env.NODE_ENV` only has 2 possible values `development` and
> `production`. If this is not set to that value you'll run into all kinds
> of library edge cases (especially in node_modules) where you get
> severely de-optimized results. E.g. if you run a performance test
> you'll get significantly worse results if `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not
> set to production

Comment: Also note that there is an open RFC for adding built-in `APP_ENV` support: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25764

Answer (score 5):

## Short Answer

1. Put your dev-env secrets in `.env.dev`
2. Put your prod-env secrets in `.env.prod`
3. Don't save secrets in `.env.local`. They will be brought there next.
4. Add following to your `package.json` script.

```
"build-dev": "cp .env.dev .env.local && yarn build",
"build-prod": "cp .env.prod .env.local && yarn build"
```

6. Upvote & Enjoy if it worked.

Additionally,

1. You may want to add a variable `APP_ENV`.
2. Set it to `development` and `production` based on file.
3. Access `process.env.APP_ENV` based on your script invocation.

Keep in mind, `process.env.NODE_ENV` will always be `production` in all the 3 scripts above.
And don't store your env files in standard format that nextjs's build command can detect.
Perhaps use `.env.dev`, `.env.stg`, `.env.prod`

## Long Answer

*Well this is Mid-2023 and I wish there was a straightforward solution. Here's what works for me coming from React/vite to Nextjs with 2 different environments file.*

---

Using [Rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486419/3556531) I first renamed

- `.env.development` to `.env.dev`
- `.env.production` to `.env.prod`

so that next.js doesn't pick them automatically during builds but they stay on local system.

If I don't do that then precedence kicks in and picks `.env.production` during deployment to my `dev` environment which I don't want.

Next I modified my scripts in package.json as

```
"build":"yarn build"

"predeploy": "cp .env.dev .env.local",
"deploy": "firebase use development && firebase hosting:channel:deploy dev",

"predeployprod": "cp .env.prod .env.local",
"deployprod": "firebase use production && firebase deploy -P production"
```

Read about [Next JS Precedence Order](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order) briefly.

What this does is based on my "invocation" whether I want to deploy to dev/prod env it supplies the right secrets to the `.env.local` file.

*For example, Say I want to deploy to dev.
I run `yarn deploy` -> automatically runs `yarn predeploy` first setting my dev-secrets to `.env.local`. Secondly it runs the build.*

You might wonder where's nextjs's build command?
`firebase deploy` takes care of that and runs it behind the scene.

If you aren't using firebase following could suffice.

```
"build-dev": "cp .env.dev .env.local && yarn build",
"build-prod": "cp .env.prod .env.local && yarn build"
```

Comment: Where in your firebase project / environment does it know to run `build-prod` vs `build-dev`?

Comment: @conor909 you put them on `package.json` as mentioned above and invoke them as needed with yarn or npm as `yarn build-dev` or `npm run build-dev`

Answer (score 0):

We solve it from our pipeline. Basically, when we build the image:

```
copy ".env.%ENVIROMENT%" to "./.env"
```

Then, if it finds a .env file, it always uses that.

You need to configure the value of %ENVIROMENT% in each pipeline you use for production or development (or make it recognize which pipeline it is).

If you have different steps during the image build, you could even use different environments for building and running.

Dockerfile example (this is not the best Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:16.17.3-buster-slim as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY . ./
COPY .env.%ENVFILE_NEXT% ./.env
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16.17.3-buster-slim as dst

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY --from=builder /app/next-i18next.config.js ./next-i18next.config.js
#
COPY .env.%ENVFILE_NEXT% ./.env

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```