# How to use different .env files with nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

I would like to have different configuration files for the environment variables and be able to use them in my next project. I saw the example with [dotenv](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-dotenv).

But I don't like to define the variables in the .env file and also define them in the config.next.js file. if for some reason I put the variables in the .env file but forget to put them in the config.next.js file the code starts having problems. 
Theres is a way to do it more eficiently?

**My scripts in package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint pages --ext .ts,.tsx,.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "dev:production": "dotenv next"
},
```

**My .env vars**

```
TITULO=react, typescript, material ui App
```

**Component**

```
import { NextPage }          from 'next';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

interface HelloWorldProps {
  nombre: string,
  saludo?: string
}


const HelloWorld: FunctionComponent<HelloWorldProps> = ({ nombre, saludo = 'noches' }: HelloWorldProps) => (
  <>
    <h1>Hola {nombre} buenas {saludo}</h1>
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line multiline-ternary */}
    <h2>{process.env.TITULO ? 'hola' : 'adios'}</h2>
  </>
);

const Home: NextPage = () => <HelloWorld nombre="cristian" />;

export default Home;
```

Comment: I answered this on a similar post here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724510/3556531

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Next 9.4 has built-in support for .env files: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

But, in case you want to have multiple .env files, like:

- .env.development
- .env.staging
- .env.prestaging
- .env.production

It would be impossible to do with a built-in env variables support. There's only 3 environments that officially supported for now, it's: "development", "test", "production". With `next dev` you use "development", `next build && next start` uses "production" environment.

If you need to build for production environment, but using ".env.staging" for example, then you need to add [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) package, and add this line to your package.json:

```
"build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn build && yarn start"
```

Next would make a production build with ".env.staging" variables.

Comment: With next dev you use "development", next build && next start uses "production" environment and how to run in "test" environment then?

Comment: This works good to start the application locally. But then when you deploy in my case it it doesn't load environment variables. I have one default .env and on build I add .env.staging for example. On deployed version only variables from .env are showing? Can you help me with that?

Comment: This is ok, but it wont work with the Docker build once run anywhere as you would need to build with different commands. This is the solution: https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env

Comment: Great tip about `cmd-env`. Btw, looks like it should be an option on nextJs =)

Comment: @WendellPereira It definitely does, it is ridiculous we need to install external libraries for handling environments --'

Comment: This does not work with `next: 9.5.3` and `env-cmd: ^10.1.0`. It keeps load the production env no matter what env supplied to `env-cmd`:
`$ env-cmd -f .env.development next start
info  - Loaded env from /Users/username/projects/ex/.env.production`

Comment: @PhạmTuấnAnh I am facing exactly the same issues, did you found out any other solution that worked ?

Comment: @zsubzwary unfortunately no. I end up just place all env variables in the .env.production file then comment/uncomment them accordingly

Comment: Try this answer I wrote. It works with Next 13 and doesn't have any dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724510/3556531

Comment: Next 14. If there is a `.env` (for development mode), it ignores my custom file (`env-cmd --file .env.staging next build`) and loads `.env`. If there is no `.env`, I get plenty of errors during build. No solution for me.

Answer (score 32):

The issue with most of these answers is they go against the principal of "build once run everywhere", in reality most of us are using this technique build and run with Docker containers. It's not possible to have multiple build commands like this, and it would be bad practice.

Better have your environment available at runtime. We created a package that allows next static optimisation and still have runtime env vars via `window.__ENV`

https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env

This works by generating an environment config object at runtime from whitelisted env vars:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-env -- next dev", // where .env.${APP_ENV}
    "start": "react-env --env APP_ENV -- next start" // where .env.${APP_ENV}
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Coming from other environments and being absolutely dumbfounded that NextJS does it this way, thank you for being a voice of reason.

Comment: Also been googling around for a while, just confused at the "default" way env is handled in next - thank you

Comment: How to pick an API base URL from the process environment after the build? If the actual URL is unknown during the build and will be passed to the Docker container on startup?

Comment: see the documentation for this package. You can do that.

Comment: I was supremely frustrated to find that NextJS expected me to build seperate bundles for staging and production environments, this package is a great approach to solving a common problem and should be part of the core framework

Answer (score 21):

You can have different .env files in nextjs with following two ways:

**1. Using env-cmd package**

Provide the path to your environment file in the scripts like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd path/to/prod/env/file next start",
    "start:dev": "env-cmd path/to/prod/env/file next dev",   
    "build:dev": "env-cmd path/to/dev/env/file next build",
    "build:test": "env-cmd path/to/test/env/file next build",
    "build:stage": "env-cmd path/to/stage/env/file next build",
    "build": "env-cmd path/to/stage/prod/file next build",        
},
```

**2. Using dotenv package**

In your next.config.js file add following:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: `${process.env.ENVIRONMENT}` });

module.exports = {
      // your configs
}
```

and in your scripts, provide that ENVIRONMENT variable like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/prod/env/file next start",
    "start:dev": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/dev/env/file next dev",
    "build:dev": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/dev/env/file next build",
    "build:test": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/test/env/file next build",
    "build:stage": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/stage/env/file next build",
    "build": "ENVIRONMENT=path/to/stage/prod/file next build",        
},
```

**NOTE**: The thing is do not to put your .env* files in the root folder, otherwise NEXT will auto-pick from your .evn* files and it only supports production and development stages. So it'll ignore other .env.my-stage files.

Comment: hi. is the `env-cmd` needed for the `next start` command? I think the variables are inlined during the build and `next start` just runs that build, am I right?

Comment: @RichardTrembecký, yes that's correct. Without production build, `next start` won't work and `env-cmd` injects variables during build.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\admin\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

Comment: for env-cmd, you can use -f to force using a specific env file if your envs are on root folder: "env-cmd -f .env.dev next build"

Answer (score 8):

This day and age you shouldn't need to install anything extra to implement multiple environment configuration! See GitHub repo [NextJS template with config management](https://github.com/piouson/nextjs-tailwindcss-template)

[Next.js v9.4 and up has a more intuitive and ergonomic way for adding environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables):

```json
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "build-dev": "TARGET_ENV=development next build && next export",
    "build-staging": "TARGET_ENV=staging next build && next export",
    "test": "jest --watch"
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "env.json",
  "development": {
    "APP_ENV": "development"
  },
  "production": {
    "APP_ENV": "production"
  },
  "staging": {
    "APP_ENV": "staging"
  },
  "test": {
    "APP_ENV": "test"
  }
}
```

```js
// next.config.js v9.4+
const envConfig = require('./env.json')
const environment = process.env.TARGET_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV

const nextConfig = {
  env: envConfig[environment], // getEnvConfig()
}
module.exports = nextConfig

function getEnvConfig() { // for multi-file config
  try {
    return require(`./env-${environment}.json`)
  } catch (err) {
    return require('./env.json')
  }
}
```

```bash
npm run dev # process.env.APP_ENV=development
npm run build # process.env.APP_ENV=production
npm run build-dev # process.env.APP_ENV=development
npm run build-staging # process.env.APP_ENV=staging
npm run test # process.env.APP_ENV=test
```

Comment: that doesn't make much sense to me in a container world. We shouldn't be building per-environment. The build should be only one and use ENV variables at run time, which is what ENV VARS are for, right?

Comment: hate it or leave it, today many organisations still using static site exports dumped in wherever random cloud bucket in production..

Answer (score 4):

`npm i dotenv`

Then add below code to `next.config.js`, restart the application and you are good to go!

```
// next.config.js

require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(process.env)
    )
    return config
  }
}
```

If your .env file is not located in same folder as `next.config.js` add path to your config like below,

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'path/to/.env' })
```

Comment: Adding the config.plugins.push line worked for me with Next 9.4.0; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested to use `.yml` file for easy management of environment variables, here's how I did it.

Install a plugin **`yenv`** in `devDependencies`.

Add the below config in **next.config.js** :

```
const path = require("path");
const yenv = require("yenv");
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require("next/constants");

module.exports = (phase) => {
  const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER;
  const NEXT_ENV = isDev ? "development" : process.env.APP_ENV;
  const rawEnv = yenv(path.resolve(".env.yml"), { raw: true, env: NEXT_ENV });
  
  return {
    ...some other config,
    env: getEnvVars(rawEnv, isDev).raw,
    compress: true,
  };
};

function getEnvVars(rawEnv, dev) {
  const NEXT_PUBLIC = /^NEXT_PUBLIC_/i;
  const raw = Object.keys(rawEnv)
    .filter((key) => NEXT_PUBLIC.test(key))
    .reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = rawEnv[key];
      return env;
    }, {});
  // Stringify all values so we can feed into Webpack DefinePlugin
  const stringified = {
    "process.env": Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
      return env;
    }, {}),
  };
  return { raw, stringified };
}
```

Now just add different build commands based on environment in **`package.json`** scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build:production": "APP_ENV=production next build",
    "build:staging": "APP_ENV=staging next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
```

Now you can use your environment variables via a single file **`.env.yml`** like this :

```
base:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY : ""
  NEXT_PUBLIC_ANOTHER_SECRET: ""

development:
  ~compose: base
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY: "bnbnfjf"

staging:
  ~compose: base
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY: "absadsad"

production:
  ~compose: base
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY: "lasjdasodsdsad"
```

Now you can call `npm run build:production` to load production env vars and `npm run build:staging` for staging env vars.

This provides the benefit of having any number of envs for your use case. You will just have to add a build command, and update env vars in `.env.yml` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a very elegant solution for me, compared to the others.

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

1. Put your dev-env secrets in `.env.dev`
2. Put your prod-env secrets in `.env.prod`
3. Don't save secrets in `.env.local`. They will be brought there next.
4. Add following to your `package.json` script.

```
"build-dev": "cp .env.dev .env.local && yarn build",
"build-prod": "cp .env.prod .env.local && yarn build"
```

5. Upvote & Enjoy if it worked.

Additionally,

1. You may want to add a variable `APP_ENV`.
2. Set it to `development` and `production` based on file.
3. Access `process.env.APP_ENV` based on your script invocation.

## Long Answer

*Well this is Mid-2023 and I wish there was a straightforward solution. Here's what works for me coming from React/vite to Nextjs with 2 different environments file.*

---

Using [Rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486419/3556531) I first renamed

- `.env.development` to `.env.dev`
- `.env.production` to `.env.prod`

so that next.js doesn't pick them automatically during builds but they stay on local system.

If I don't do that then precedence kicks in and picks `.env.production` during deployment to my `dev` environment which I don't want.

Next I modified my scripts in package.json as

```
"build":"yarn build"

"predeploy": "cp .env.dev .env.local",
"deploy": "firebase use development && firebase hosting:channel:deploy dev",

"predeployprod": "cp .env.prod .env.local",
"deployprod": "firebase use production && firebase deploy -P production"
```

Read about [Next JS Precedence Order](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order) briefly.

What this does is based on my "invocation" whether I want to deploy to dev/prod env it supplies the right secrets to the `.env.local` file.

*For example, Say I want to deploy to dev.
I run `yarn deploy` -> automatically runs `yarn predeploy` first setting my dev-secrets to `.env.local`. Secondly it runs the build.*

You might wonder where's nextjs's build command?
`firebase deploy` takes care of that and runs it behind the scene.

If you aren't using firebase following could suffice.

```
"build-dev": "cp .env.dev .env.local && yarn build",
"build-prod": "cp .env.prod .env.local && yarn build"
```

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724510/3556531).

Comment: `npm run build-dev` gives "cp is not recognized as an internal or external command" in windows powershell but works in bash.

Comment: @abitcode you need to use a Linux compatible shell

Comment: Where do you tell different firebase projects to use different scripts to build or start?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use it without any 3rd party library you can expose it from the script directly with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` at the start of the script, for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV=development next dev"
}
```

than use it with

```
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV); // >>> development
```

Comment: I guess someone did not got it correct, or maybe version problems, but I am using it for many projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) and then set up different `.env` files for different environments in your `package.json`. Something like:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev:production": "dotenv next", // Uses .env file
    "dev:staging": "dotenv -e .env.staging next" // Uses .env.staging file
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's giving me an error of `dotenv` not found. Although I have installed it and working properly with local file

Comment: `dotenv -e .env.development next build` still loads production config

Comment: it still load the production env. I end up with just comment / uncomment variables inside the production env file. so ridiculous!!!

Comment: `NODE_ENV` determines if `.env.development` or `.env.production` file is loaded.
You should use different env file names for your "application environment" by using `.env.app.development` and `.env.app.production` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still seek a solution for their faulty project, in my case my npm run dev script was "next dev src/"
Getting rid of that immediately started loading .env files for me.
Maybe give it a try.

[A screenshot of my lovely fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkPk4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach that first "unloads" the incorrect dotenv files and then loads the correct ones.

```js
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: 0 */
const  dotenv= require('dotenv')
const dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand')
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/dist/shared/lib/constants')

module.exports = (phase) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER && process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'development') {
    unloadDevEnvVars()
    loadCorrectEnvVars()
  }

  return {}
}

function unloadDevEnvVars() {
  const developmentEnvVars = {}

  dotenv.config({ path: './.env.development.local', processEnv: developmentEnvVars })
  dotenv.config({ path: './.env.development', processEnv: developmentEnvVars  })

  Object.keys(developmentEnvVars).forEach(developmentEnvVarName => {
    delete process.env[developmentEnvVarName]
  })
}

function loadCorrectEnvVars() {
  dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config({ path: `./.env.${process.env.ENVIRONMENT}.local` }))
  dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config({ path: `./.env.${process.env.ENVIRONMENT}` }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use default nextjs env files you can use the `parse` method from `dotenv`.

Example:

`next.config.mjs`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const env = fs.readFileSync('path.to.your.custom.env.file')
const config = dotenv.parse(env)

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    ...config,
  }
}

export default nextConfig
```

In my case, my custom env file is used in CI/CD and some variables not supported by nextjs are needed like `NODE_ENV`

In this case you can delete the variable from the config object

`next.config.mjs`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const env = fs.readFileSync('path.to.your.custom.env.file')
const config = dotenv.parse(env)

delete config.NODE_ENV

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    ...config,
  }
}

export default nextConfig
```

Answer (score -1):

[Next 9.4 support out of the box environment variables](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#new-environment-variables-support) and [included support for multiple environments](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables).

### New Environment Variables Support

- Environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment by default
- Environment variables prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` are exposed to the browser

### Exposing Environment Variables

Next.js allows you to expose variables using an environment variables file `(.env)`, with included support for multiple environments. It works like this:

- `.env` - Contains environment variables for all environments
- `.env.local` - Local variable overrides for all environments
- `.env.[environment]` - Environment variables for one environment. For example: `.env.development`
- `.env.[environment].local` - Local variable overrides for one environment. For example: `.env.development.local`

Comment: but how can I start app that would use `.env.staging`?

Comment: Reason for downvote: This thread is concerned with being able to setup NextJS to run against multiple environments like : dev, qat, uat, staging, production - the out of the box environment variables do not support this - so copy/pasting this feature from the NextJS site doesn't really answer the quesiton