# Next.js ignoring NODE_ENV=development

Tags: next.js

In my `package.json`, I have a `build` script set to build my next project as follows:

`"build": "echo \"$NODE_ENV\" && NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV next build && npm run build-server",`

The output from the command that I get is:

```
> admin-ui@1.0.0 build /usr/src/admin-ui
> echo "$NODE_ENV" && NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV next build && npm run build-server

development
Creating an optimized production build ...
```

The `echo` outputs `development` as the value for `$NODE_ENV`. However, I cannot get that passed to next. It just ignores it.

Using next.js version `9.0.5`.

Comment: what you mean with "I cannot get that passed to next"? that you cant detect the current enviroment inside next app? (ex. inside _document.js)

Comment: @nico next ignores my value of `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408007/nextjs-next-build-with-node-env-development

Comment: According to an [answer on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17032#issuecomment-691506975) using APP_ENV is suggested. That sounds like an ok solution.

Answer (score 1):

`next build` generates `production` builds

`next dev` creates a development build - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development

`Build` usually is nomenclature for production builds and `dev` for a development server.

When you do `next build` it assumes that its preparing for production and continues to do so.

Comment: This is kind of silly and I definitely believe it shouldn't ignore an explicit setting. I'm building a docker image and that's why I need to build first (prod and dev have the same Dockerfile).

Comment: Note that `NODE_ENV` is used in a [special way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408007/nextjs-next-build-with-node-env-development?noredirect=1&lq=1) in Next.js. (I could not find reliable information on how it behaves, but it definitively has a special meaning.)