# Next.js env file depending deployment stage

Tags: next.js

Let's say I am deploying Next.js in different env, for example.

1. local development
2. staging deployment
3. production deployment

Previously I hand used `.env` file with one of the framework where I could easily name the file like `.env.local`, `.env.stage` & `.env.prod` and when I run node app locally it would load `.env.local`, with `export STAGE=stage` framework would use `.env.stage`, like wise fro production.

Is that such support in Next js where I can have different `.env` file for different stage. If it is supported then how would I specify which stage Next.js is running.

Comment: The point of .env files is to provide a local environment that simulate the env vars available in the production environments. In staging and production, you don't need a .env file, you need to look up how to configure the environment in whatever platform you're using.

Comment: @jonrsharpe As per my understanding, in Next.js, env var are replaced at build time with actual values, unlike any other program where env var picked at runtime. So, even if I set env var according to platform where Next.js is deployed it wont use those variable, right?

Comment: This is still an unsolved problem in Next.js as far as I'm aware. Client side (`NEXT_PUBLIC_`) environment variables are frozen at build time.

Comment: To workaround this I'm using `@beam-australia/react-env` for ENV's I need to be changed in different environments (staging, prod), but to get build time values I still need to put them in the env.production, so I'm not completely satisfied with this solution.

Comment: Try this answer I wrote. 0 Dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724510/3556531

Answer (score 3):

Original Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724510/3556531

I am using package.json's script to copy different environment secrets to `.env.local` based on the command invoked.

```
"build-dev":"cp .env.dev .env.local && yarn build",
"build-prod":"cp .env.prod .env.local && yarn build"
```

I won't say its ideal but get the job done in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different environments, just need to follow this

For production

```
// .env.production.local
// This file is for production and run with next start or npm run start
// NODE_ENV=production
```

For development

```
// .env.development.local
// This file is for development and run when next dev or npm run dev
// NODE_ENV=development
```

For tests

```
// .env.test.local
// This file is for tests with jest or cypress for example
// NODE_ENV=test
```

If you want know more about this, [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) is the complete info about environments in next js

Update:

If you want to run more environments without next [standard](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env), you can do this manually:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "dev:staging": "APP_ENV=staging next dev",
}
...


// next.config.js
require('dotenv-flow').config({
  node_env: process.env.APP_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || 
   'development',
});

const env = {};
Object.keys(process.env).forEach((key) => {
  if (key.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC_')) {
    env[key] = process.env[key];
  }
});

module.exports = {
  env,
};
```

And when you run npm run/yarn dev:staging your staging environment from .env.staging.local will be loaded, my reference is from flybayer and you can read more [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25764)

Comment: How about beyond dev, prod and test? Like uat, stage, etc.

Comment: The standard for next is just production, development and test, if you need more, you need to change NODE_ENV to other like APP_ENV, you can read more about this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env)
I updated my answer to do that