# How to change the build shell in vuepress, to switch base between '/' and '/somedir/'

Tags: nuxt.js, vuepress

I want to build a blog with vuepress, and want to publish it to my server and github page. 
Like www.codingyang.com and https://github.com/Rackar/codingyang, but in the config.js, 'base' will be set to '/' and '/codingyang', to make the url resource correct.

Can I change different shell to build with different congfig.base ?

```
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs && node utils/bd_hm.js",
    "docs:build:gitpage": "vuepress build docs --codingyang && node utils/bd_hm.js",
    "docs:push:gitpage": "push-dir --dir=docs/.vuepress/dist --branch=gh-pages"
```

like use 'docs:build' to build dist/ with base = '/' ,and copy that to my server.

use 'docs:build:gitpage' && 'docs:push:gitpage' to set base = 'codingyang ', and use them in github Actions and github Pages for other developers?

Can I use additional parameters or determine the environment scripts to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I believe you can set the base value depending on an environment variable:

```
module.exports = {
  base: process.env.VUEPRESS_BASE || '/'
}
```

And config the environment variable in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "docs:build": "vuepress build docs && node utils/bd_hm.js",
  "docs:build:gitpage": "VUEPRESS_BASE="/codingyang/" && vuepress build docs --codingyang && node utils/bd_hm.js"
}
```

Reference:

1. [Issue #560](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/560)
2. [How to set environment variable from within package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

Comment: Thank you very much. 感谢老铁。 ``` "docs:build:gitpage": "export VUEPRESS_BASE=/codingyang/|| set VUEPRESS_BASE=/codingyang/&&vuepress build docs && node utils/bd_hm.js" ``` Following your reply and the references, I got this worked!