# Setting argv in the package.json and running a different script

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json, npm-scripts, npm-run

I have two versions of my application, for one I set --extended, and for the other not, like this

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "extended": "webpack --mode production --extended",
    // ...
 }
```

Now, in my webpack, I access the extended like this

```js
module.exports = (_env,argv)=> {
   argv.extended
}
```

I am trying to improve this in a cross platform way to do something like

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "extended": "--extended npm run build"       
  }
```

as to run the `build` script from `extended` but still access the `--extended` variable.

I there a way to achieve this? Thank you

I read this whole question [How to set environment variables from within package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json) but can't find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `scripts` section of your *package.json* to the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode production",
  "extended": "npm run build -- --extended"
}
```

**Explanation:**

As stated in the `npm-run-script` documentation which can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script.html):

> ... The special option `--` is used by [`getopt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script:

So, essentially when you run the following command via your CLI:

```
$ npm run extended
```

npm invokes the `extended` script, which then runs the `build` script and passes the `--extended` argument to the end of it (i.e. it passes `--extended` to the end of the `build` script).

---

#### Is there another way?

Yes, you could also consider simplifying the `scripts` section of your *package.json* further by deleting your `extended` script completely.

For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Then you can do either of the following:

1. Run the following command via your CLI:

   ```
   $ npm run build
   ```

   This will to invoke your `build` script *without* the `--extended` argument/option.
2. Or run the following command  via your CLI instead:

   ```
   $ npm run build -- --extended
   ```

   This will invoke your `build` script *with* the `--extended` argument/option.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer