# Load separate .env from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

```
"start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon ./bin/www",
"start:test": "set NODE_ENV=testing&&nodemon ./bin/www",
```

I have two separate .env files **dev.env** and **test.env** 
I want to load dev.env on *npm run start:dev* and load test.env on *npm run start:test*

I have searched every where on the Internet, but no help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set node env in npm script. to import file you need to write code on your server file.

import dotenv in your server file

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
or
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
```

use below code to import particular env file.

```
let envConfig={}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  if (fs.existsSync(".env.development")) {
    envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(".env.development"));
  } 

} else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "testing"){
 if (fs.existsSync(".env.test")) {
    envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(".env.test"));
  } 
}

 for (const k in envConfig) {
    process.env[k] = envConfig[k];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dotenv` [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) loads a file called `.env` by default, but this behaviour can be overriden. So you can do something like:

```
const { config } = require('dotenv')
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    config({ path: '/full/path/to/your/dev.env' })
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') {
    config({ path: '/full/path/to/your/test.env' })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61052350/10355546) has a solution for you:

```
scripts: {
  "set-env:production": "export $(cat .production.env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs)",
  "set-env:development": "export $(cat .env | grep \"^[^#;]\" |xargs)",
}
```