# Google Cloud Throwing Error : Could not load the default credentials in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I have store this service account key (my-key.json) file in my downloads folder (ubuntu)
and then i run this command into my console

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"`

according to
[google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). Now i am running this code but it throws me error.

```
const language = require('@google-cloud/language');

const quickstart = async function () {
  // Instantiates a client
  const client = new language.LanguageServiceClient();
 
  // The text to analyze
  const text = 'Hello, world!';
 
  const document = {
    content: text,
    type: 'PLAIN_TEXT',
  };
 
  // Detects the sentiment of the text
  const [result] = await client.analyzeSentiment({document: document});
  const sentiment = result.documentSentiment;
 
  console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
  console.log(`Sentiment score: ${sentiment.score}`);
  console.log(`Sentiment magnitude: ${sentiment.magnitude}`);
}


quickstart();
```

```
**ERORR** -
(node:13928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/home/hardy/Documents/personal/project/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:154:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/home/hardy/Documents/personal/project/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:485:17)
    at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/home/hardy/Documents/personal/project/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:88:24)
    at async GrpcClient.createStub (/home/hardy/Documents/personal/project/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:213:23)
```

Comment: this library may solve your problem in both local and cloud environment such as heroku https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-credentials-helper please check it out

Answer (score 18):

If you are using `node <file-name>.js` to initialize your code, you should update the command to

> `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json" node <file-name>.js`

This will make the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS available inside your node-environment.

However, as a long-term solution, I would suggest creating a `.env` file and storing the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"`  in that file.

And then using the `dotenv` package at the beginning of  your `js` file in the following manner:

> `require('dotenv').config();`

You can also refer to `https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090755/7743705` for understanding how to set environment variables in `pacakge.json`.

Comment: This was exactly the issue! I tried everything including adding it to the environment  but passing directly to the node command worked!  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json" node <file-name>.js

Comment: @RajaRao Glad that it helped. If your issue is resolevd by my answer, I would request you to kindly accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: "long-term solution" worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also just attach it to process.env before importing the @google-cloud npm library like so:

```
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json";

const language = require('@google-cloud/language');
```

**Why it works**:

I suspect google checks for the environment variable when you import it, not when you actually invoke the methods, which is it's necessary to set the variable first.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run using npm without setting credentials each time

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]/credentials.json&& nodemon server.js"
},
```

For further reason on how to use env you can visit [How to set environment variables from within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json/27090755#27090755) for more comprehensive answers.