# ENV vars are not set through npm start (run-script) (on Windows git-bash)

Tags: windows, npm, environment-variables, git-bash, npm-scripts

I have installed git-bash to be able to set env vars like that `<VAR>=<value> node ...`, but now it's working only if I run node. If I do it through npm start (`"start": "ENV=development node server.js"`), ENV would not be set. That's strange.

But if I do `ENV=development npm start` or `ENV=development node server.js`, it sets.

Where could the problem be?

P.S. I run bash through typing `bash` in powershell (I tried to do bash selectable in visual code terminal, even though I added ../git/bin/ to the PATH I still don't see it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables from within package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json#answer-61525615) specifically. Essentially, redefine your npm script as: `"start": "env ENV=development node server.js"` (note the initial [env](https://ss64.com/bash/env.html) prefix). Alternatively for cross-platform utilize the [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) package.

Comment: @RobC that's it. I haven't scrolled down enough in that question. It solves this issue, but not the main, I wanted to set env vars in Windows and Linux the same way. I don't use dotenv because I will have to create multiple .env for development and production (it is not recommended by dotenv doc).

Comment: Have you tried: **1)** Installing [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) in your project: `npm i -D cross-env`. **2)** Redefining your npm script as `"start": "cross-env ENV=development node server.js"` - that should work for both Windows and Linux.