# npm run with NODE_ENV as parameter

Tags: heroku, npm

How can I pass `NODE_ENV` into `npm run` command as parameter?

Example `package.json` file:

```
NODE_ENV=8080

...
    "script": {
        "start": "http-server --port $NODE_ENV" // or something similar that
    }
...
```

Note that `NODE_ENV` is set by another process, the `npm run` only can be read from it.

I met this problem when deploying my app into heroku (they will automatically set `NODE_ENV`). I found another solution for this problem on heroku but I still wanna to know if there is a way to pass `NODE_ENV` into `npm run` command.

Comment: Any tool acceptance ? Is there a problem for using 3rd party tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables can be used directly, as you have tried to do:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo $FOO"
  }
}
```

`yarn start` and `npm run start` will both echo the value of the `FOO` environment variable if you run this start script. I think you have two other problems.

First, you are trying to use the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to set the port your application listens on. [Heroku provides this value via the *`PORT`* environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers), not `NODE_ENV`. [`NODE_ENV` will contain something like `production`](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production).

Second, you are trying to set an environment variable in your `package.json`. [This is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954560/354577), but it will override the value Heroku sets. Instead, consider using a `.env` file in development. Its contents can look something like this:

```
PORT=8080
```

You'll need tooling to load this file and populate your environment. [`dotenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954560/354577) is a popular choice. Note that your `.env` file should *not* be committed, so consider also adding it to your `.gitignore`.

There are other methods to set environment variables in your development environment, and any of them will work if you prefer.

Putting this all together, your `package.json` should contain something like

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server --port $PORT"
  }
}
```

Comment: My fault was think of port value is set by `$NODE_ENV` instead of `$PORT`. So using `"http-server --port $PORT"` instead of `"http-server --port $NODE_ENV"` fix my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to accept value inside string in double quotes which is wrong. You can access in the following ways:

Option 1:
You need to concat two strings.

```
NODE_ENV=8080

"script": {
    "start": "http-server --port "+NODE_ENV
}
```

Option 2:
You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
NODE_ENV=8080

"script": {
    "start": `http-server --port ${NODE_ENV}`
}
```

In Option 2 NODE_ENV will be replaced with the actual value of the variable

Comment: Please note that this is `package.json` file, not javascript file so you can not write javascript code here. So either concat string or template literals not work

Comment: Have you added the NODE_ENV to environment variables? Because the structure is the same I tried with different variables