# Can not get environment variable defined in npm script using typescript in windows

Tags: node.js, typescript

I define environment variable in npm script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start:live": "tsc",
    "start:run": "nodemon build/server.js",
    "start:dev:windows": "SET NODE_ENV=production && concurrently npm:start:build npm:start:run",
    "seeding": "node build/seeding.js"
  },
```

But when I retrieve this `NODE_ENV` it is available but return `false` when I compare with same string.

```
console.log('NODE_ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production');
```

Below is attached snapshot of my terminal

[image: Output of of my terminal]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables from within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

Comment: No this question does not satisficed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry in the package json adds a space to the end of the value `production`. It is actually `production`  (notice the space). The `&&` symbol should touch the end of the value.

In the image you have attached, you can see there are two spaces right after the second string of your console.log result. This is why the third console.log entry return false - because, you try to compare it without the space trailing it.

Correct line:

```
"SET NODE_ENV=production&&concurrently npm:start:build npm:start:run"
```

Comment: Ptoblem is, we have 5 devs with windows machines and only 1 of them have the problem. I am assuming this is a Git Bash problem?

Comment: It should be. If the files are identical, they should behave the same. Check the Node version too.