# Parametrization of npm package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless, npm-scripts

What is alternative for npm6 .npmrc $npm_config_* vars in npm7 (config
vars were deprecated).

Example of usage in the script:

```
"package": "sam package --profile $npm_config_awsProfile --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $npm_config_s3BucketName --output-template-file template-out.yaml",
```

Example of .npmrc

```
awsProfile = "au"
s3BucketName = "production-tmp-bucket-ap-southeast-2"
```

Answer (score 0):

**### OPTION 1:**
Don't use the Npm environment, use it only as a stepping stone to JavaScript. Pass any parameters you need through Npm to your Javascript.

***e.g.***
*In your package.json scripts section:*

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-var node env/build.js"
 }
```

build script defined to run javascript under node - optional use of the cross-var package to help it work on windows
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var)

*To invoke on the command line:*
`npm run build -- <YourFirstArgHere>`

Note space after --

*To access in your javascript:*
`let firstParm = process.argv[2]`

**### OPTION 2:**
Use standard environment variables to capture "Start state" mentioned above (Jun21).

(NOTE: I have not tried this technique, and am not sure if the environment variable value will persist between preScript - Script and postScript npm executions - assuming folks know about this: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts/)

*Details on Setting these environment variables here:*
[How to set environment variables from within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

*Of particular interest is comment 14:*

> if you want to use the env var inside the script itself you need to prepend $, for example if you run mode=prod npm run print and you have a script in your package.json called print "print": "echo environment '$mode'" it will print environment 'prod' – Jonathan Morales Vélez