# How to use TIMING=1 eslint to measure rule Performance in Windows OS

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, eslint, package.json

In ESLint [official website](https://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/developer-guide/working-with-rules#per-rule-performance), there is a paragraph, called `Per-rule Performance`.

It states that

"setting the `TIMING` environment variable will trigger the display, upon linting completion, of the ten longest-running rules, along with their individual running time and relative performance impact as a percentage of total rule processing time".

```
$ TIMING=1 eslint lib
Rule                    | Time (ms) | Relative
:-----------------------|----------:|--------:
no-multi-spaces         |    52.472 |     6.1%
camelcase               |    48.684 |     5.7%
no-irregular-whitespace |    43.847 |     5.1%
valid-jsdoc             |    40.346 |     4.7%
handle-callback-err     |    39.153 |     4.6%
space-infix-ops         |    35.444 |     4.1%
no-undefined            |    25.693 |     3.0%
no-shadow               |    22.759 |     2.7%
no-empty-class          |    21.976 |     2.6%
semi                    |    19.359 |     2.3%
```

However, when I add

```
"lint-js": "TIMING=1 eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/js --cache --cache-strategy metadata"
```

in the `"scripts"` in `package.json` and run it with

```
npm run lint-js
```

in my `Windows OS`, I get

```
'TIMING' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to run `TIMING=1` with `eslint` in Windows OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researching, I found a simple way to solve cross-platform issue.

```
"lint-js": "export TIMING=1 || set TIMING=1&& eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/js --cache --cache-strategy metadata"
```

The vertical bars are needed as otherwise Windows would crash on the unrecognized `export`.

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36373133/13230147

Answer (score 3):

In Windows environment variables should be set using the `set` command.

Try the following from the command line:

```
set TIMING=1
npx eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/js --cache --cache-strategy metadata
```

Comment: Is it possible to add it to `package.json`, so that I can just run `npm run lint-js`?

Comment: Sure. I would use `cross-env` as GOTO 0 already wrote.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options: work with the [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) command or use an external tool like cross-env:

##### Using set (Windows only)

```json
"lint-js": "set TIMING=1 && eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/js --cache --cache-strategy metadata"
```

##### Using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Install with:

```
npm install -D cross-env
```

Then change the script command to:

```json
"lint-js": "cross-env TIMING=1 eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/js --cache --cache-strategy metadata"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Windows, my work team use Mac you can try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env, that worked for me.

```
"lint": "cross-env TIMING=1 next lint",
```

Answer (score 0):

use `set TIMING=1` in cmd or `$env:TIMING=1` in powershell