# How do i run one script on development and another on production

Tags: node.js, powershell

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "$env:NODE_ENV=\"development\"; nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "$env:NODE_ENV=\"production\"; nodemon server.js"
  },
```

I want to set the NODE_ENV variable to development when i run 'start' script and to production when i run 'start:prod' script but i get error that says:

$env:NODE__ENV="development"; nodemon server.js
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[image: Error image]

Comment: perhaps this questions will provide some inspiration for your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json

Comment: The error suggests that it is `cmd.exe` rather than PowerShell that is trying to execute the commands.