# Command line arguments in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, command-line-arguments

How can I provide command line arguments for a vuejs application?
I use vue 3 for my frontend that communicates with the python backend (flask) via axios.
Right now, I am setting the baseURL for axios in my main.js like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL ='http://localhost:1234/';
```

To be more flexible, I want to read the path ('http://localhost:1234/') from command line, but I don't understand how to do that.

I'm starting the frontend with npm like this, providing the frontend's host and port:

```
npm run --prefix frontend dev -- --host frontendHostName --port frontendPortNumber
```

How do I extend this by custom command line parameters like for backend communication, e.g.  --backendHost backendHostName etc.? And how do I access those within my javascript?

I am new to JavaScript and Vue and I already read some suggestions, but I still don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: I don't think you can read it from command line, but you should be able to read it from environment variables, then do `frontendHostName="name"  npm run ...` (or use a .env file)

Comment: "frotnend", being a browser? there is no command line arguments for a web page in a browser

Comment: Thanks so much @mousetail. No command line arguments as I am used to from other languages, but I ended up using the .env file and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set a variable on the command line and use it in the code, but the correct thing is to use the `.env` file.

Remembering that the `.env` file may have other postfixes for each environment, but it is not very common to be used since depending on where the application is deployed you will configure the variables in a **docker**, on the platform itself (for example **netlify**, **versel**, ...).

#### Mode via .env file

You will create an `.env` file at the root of the project and correctly access the value of the variable in the project through `process.env.NomeVariavel`.

Example

```
const apiHostIp = process.env.VITE_API_HOST;
const apiHostPort = process.env.VITE_API_PORT;

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://" + apiHostIp + ":" + apiHostPort + "/";
```

#### Mode via command line

If you want to set it from the command line you will need to install the lib [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and change your command line to:

```
cross-env VITE_API_HOST=127.0.0.1 VITE_API_PORT=5000 RestanteCommand
```

**Note:** *Remembering that **RestanteComando** is the command to start the application that is in `package.json`, observer that you are using vite, it must be something like this/was in `package.json`*

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build"
}
```

it will look like this later

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env VITE_API_HOST=127.0.0.1 VITE_API_PORT=5000 vite",
  "build": "vite build"
}
```

In some operating systems, it may happen that you don't read the defining variable as I explained (windows mainly), this is the reason for using it.

About lib [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), you can see in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356976/1939621) and in the npm of the lib itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

In my project I created a .env file on root level next to my index.html.

I added the environment varibles (which I thought should be the command line arguments) like this:

```
VITE_API_HOST=127.0.0.1
VITE_API_PORT=5000
```

And then in my main.js I could access those easily with

```
const apiHostIp = import.meta.env.VITE_API_HOST;
const apiHostPort = import.meta.env.VITE_API_PORT;

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://" + apiHostIp + ":" + apiHostPort + "/";
```