# can'f find the "process.env.NODE_ENV"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, environment-variables

The variable `process.env.NODE_ENV` always bothers me every time I see it in a config file, especially `webpack.config.js`. Where can I find this? Because sometimes I want to change it's value to `production` instead of `development`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set any environmental variable like `NODE_ENV` while running your applications.

**Linux/Mac**

```
NODE_ENV=production node myapp.js
```

**Windows/Powershell**

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production" ; node myapp.js
```

You can access environmental variable NODE_ENV inside your myapp.js by

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.NODE_ENV` is `Node.js` environment.

With the help of this mostly we decide our deployment environment in which we are deploying the code.

It can be `development`,`stag` or `production`.

We can do other stuff on `env`, it's up to us.

to set in `Linux`

> export NODE_ENV=production

on `Windows`

> set NODE_ENV=production

**Example**

`config.js`

```
{development:{
//your `env` value
},
production:{
//Your `env` value
}}
```

Now on the basis of `NODE_ENV` your env will be set

Comment: so you can only set it in command line rather than initialize it in a config file?

Comment: No, you can set with code as well, for better understand, you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560844/node-js-how-to-set-environment-variables-in-code