# How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to the whole **nodejs**/**reactjs** world so apologies if my question sounds silly. I am currently playing around with [reactabular.js](https://github.com/reactabular/reactabular).

Whenever I do a `npm start` it always runs on `localhost:8080`.

How do I change it to run on `0.0.0.0:8080` to make it publicly accessible? I have been trying to read the source code in the above repo but failed to find the file which sets this setting.

Also, to add to that - how do I make it run on port `80` if that is at all possible?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Something like this worked for me. I am guessing this should work for you.

Run webpack-dev using this

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

And set this in webpack.config.js

```
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:80',
     config.paths.demo
 ]
```

**Note** If you are using hot loading, you will have to do this.

Run webpack-dev using this

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

And set this in webpack.config.js

```
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:80',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
     config.paths.demo
 ],

....
plugins:[new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to this but would like to use redux for my client script. The problem is that the application is a .net application that serves the content and json endpoints. So to do this during development I need to add `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` to the page and install some cross domain allowing plugin? These tools look interesting but seem to assume your server is node as well or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this will help me: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy I would think to use proxy for everything except requests for javascript files and some requests made by the webpack server, hotloader and redux timetravel. so `/data:image ...`, `... .js` and `/sockjs-node...`

Comment: If you get Invalid Host Header, you may need to set disableHostCheck to true in webpack.serve.config.js. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/882. Depending on your situation, it may be a security hole so be careful.

Comment: Btw, be careful when binding 0.0.0.0 in public places where someone else may connect to your device. It may lead to your data being stolen. You may need a firewall for the dev server, like this one: github.com/funbox/webpack-dev-server-firewall

Answer (score 151):

This is how I did it and it seems to work pretty well.

In you webpack.config.js file add the following:

```
devServer: {
    inline:true,
    port: 8008
  },
```

Obviously you can use any port that is not conflicting with another.  I mention the conflict issue only because I spent about 4 hrs. fighting an issue only to discover that my services were running on the same port.

Comment: i take it this is instead of specifying the host and port in the entry section of the config file?

Comment: Could you please add a link to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver)?

Comment: Simply adding inline:true worked for me.
BTW the webpack file I edited was 'webpack.dev.conf.js (as of Mar 2018).

Comment: The opposite for me: `inline:true` caused an error:`[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'inline'. These properties are valid: ...` Removing the inline attribute made it work fine.

Answer (score 86):

Configure webpack (in webpack.config.js) with:

```
devServer: {
  // ...
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80,
  // ...
}
```

Comment: it's not working for for. devServer: {
       inline: true,
 host: '0.0.0.0',
       port: 8088
    
   },

Comment: Its working for me when I use(webpack.config):
 devServer: {
    host:'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    port: 8089
  },

Comment: This solved a very closely related problem for me while trying to follow the [Modern React with Redux course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/). I'm running my development environment on Windows in a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) virtual box. The course provides absolutely no guidance about setting up the development environment.

Comment: Yeah, this addressed an issue I was having running webpack on a Cloud9 instance. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to change the port number using the above snippet but the host still didn't change. I tried to make the host 0.0.0.0 so that I can access the site from ip-address but it didn't work. Any help in how to achieve this?

Comment: It's the best answer because I'm using `package.json` file for configuration and I should use a new HOST.

Answer (score 39):

I am new to JavaScript development and ReactJS. I was unable to find an answer that works for me, until figuring it out by viewing the react-scripts code. Using ReactJS 15.4.1+ using react-scripts you can start with a custom host and/or port by using environment variables:

```
HOST='0.0.0.0' PORT=8080 npm start
```

Hopefully this helps newcomers like me.

Comment: This is the perfect answer ! Thanks

Comment: Yes, this works, or u can put HOST and PORT into .env file. Also, when it is listening on 0.0.0.0, and run npm start, in node v17, it is shown as localhost... I've got confused initially but it work nicely with tcp connection.

Comment: Best answer, +1. We had an 'invalid host header' on the web page.  We changed 0.0.0.0 to the name of the pc and voilà.  It worked like a charm.

Comment: Did not work for me in 2023

Answer (score 22):

Following worked for me -

1) In `Package.json` add this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"
}
```

2) In `webpack.config.js` add this under config object that you export:

```
devServer: {
    host: "GACDTL001SS369k", // Your Computer Name
    port: 8080
}
```

3) Now on terminal type: `npm run dev`

4) After #3 compiles and ready just head over to your browser and key in address as `http://GACDTL001SS369k:8080/`

Your app should hopefully be working now with an external URL which others can access on the same network.

PS: `GACDTL001SS369k` was my Computer Name so do replace with whatever is yours on your machine.

Comment: Out of all solutions, this one was most elegant. Thanks a ton mate.

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with some of the other answers.  (My setup is: I'm running `npm run dev`, with webpack 3.12.0, after creating my project using `vue init webpack` on an Ubuntu 18.04 virtualbox under Windows. I have vagrant configured to forward port 3000 to the host.)

- Unfortunately putting `npm run dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000` didn't work---it still ran on localhost:8080.
- Furthermore, the file `webpack.config.js` didn't exist and creating it didn't help either.
- Then I found the configuration files are now located in `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` (and `build/webpack.base.conf.js` and `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`).  However, it didn't look like a good idea to modify these files, because they actually read the HOST and PORT from `process.env`.

So I searched about [how to set process.env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/setting-environment-variables-for-node-to-retrieve) and achieved success by running the command:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 npm run dev
```

After doing this, I finally get "Your application is running here: http://0.0.0.0:3000" and I'm finally able to see it by browsing to `localhost:3000` from the host machine.

EDIT: Found another way to do it is by editing the dev host and port in `config/index.js`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in a React Application created with 'create-react-app' go to your `package.json` and change

`"start": "react-scripts start",`

to ... (**unix**)

`"start": "PORT=80 react-scripts start",`

or to ... (**win**)

`"start": "set PORT=3005 && react-scripts start"`

Comment: or edit node_modules/react-scripts/script/start.js and change DEFAULT_PORT and HOST. Just protect file on overwriting when new versions update files on npm update.

Answer (score 4):

I feel dirty for telling you this b/c of the security implications of what you're trying to do, but here you go.

> npm run dev -- -h 0.0.0.0 -p 80

Answer (score 3):

Following worked for me in JSON config file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 80 ./js/index.js"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

For me: changing the listen host worked:

```
.listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
    });
```

was changed to :

```
.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
    });
```

and the server started listening on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions above, but had no luck. I noticed this line in my project's package.json:

```
 "bin": {
"webpack-dev-server": "bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
```

},

I looked at `bin/webpack-dev-server.js` and found this line:

```
.describe("port", "The port").default("port", 8080)
```

I changed the port to 3000. A bit of a brute force approach, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this code worked. Just add it on your `package.json` file :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
},
```

And run the script "build" by running `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

For windows create file runMobile.bat

```
set PORT=8081
set HOST=192.168.3.20
npm run dev
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried this to easily use another port:

```
PORT=80 npm run dev
```