# Running react code on other machine

Tags: reactjs, npm, localhost

Hi I am working on reactJS
Would Like to understand how can I run my local React app running on http://localhost:8888/index.html#/?_k=pu9k2u through my IP address on some other machine ?

Whenever I do a "npm start" it always runs on localhost:8888

How do I change it to run on 0.0.0.0:8888 ?

I know how to change the port for the app,

Following is my webpack.congif.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: ''
  },

  devServer: {
    inline:true,
    port: 8888
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Since I am very new to reactJS kindly explain the solution given below or provide with an updated webpack.config.js

[How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33272967/6786855)

Comment: try to open http://localhost:3000/ incognito window.

Answer (score 3):

only by adding host: to webpack.config.js it worked for me

```
devServer: {
  host:'000.000.00.00',
  port: 8888
},
```

then i started react code by giving 
webpack-dev-server --host 000.000.00.00 --port 888

Comment: Merely adding these items to my webpack.config.js and running `npm start` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change hosting of the react application from `localhost` to your local ip address. (For example `10.10.54.124`), you can get it using `ipconfig` command in Windows command prompt.

Next you need to open your *port* (ex. 214) via firewall, to access from the 3rd-party machines. And after that, all of the people, how are in your local, or VPN network can access your application by link `10.10.54.124:214`.

*P.S. That would work only for people how are in your local network*

Comment: I am giving this port 8888 on my own in webpack.config.js of my react application

Comment: You can use it, at least

Comment: is there any other solution? I cant open the port via firewall

Comment: the secuirty system doesnt allow me to access such settings

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do: instead of using an IP address I tell node to use the local hostname of the computer. This is done in the `package.json` file in the scripts section with the **HOST** param, there is a **PORT** param too:

```
  {
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "start-local": "HOST='BlueLight.local' node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    ....
  }
  ...
```

My hostname is `BlueLight` so my local address is `BlueLight.local`, open the terminal and write `hostname` command to find out yours.

So any computer in my local network can open http://BlueLight.local:3000 you can even use mobile phones, and I even use iPhone or Android simulators.

Bear in mind that some security checks like WebRTC, live camera, and other https checks will not work since you don't have a SSL certificate for your local address. Some of them can be deactivated in the advanced settings of your browser.