# How can I launch using LiveServer / npm run dev/start over my local network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, liveserver

Is there a way to view my project (npm run dev/liveServer) across my home internet network so that hypothetically my iPad, phone or iMac could also view the project live as its being worked on (all connected to my wireless network) without deploying?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for LiveServer the setting you are looking to put in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) is the following:

```json
"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true
```

This will make the live server hosted on your local IP address instead of [the loopback/localhost address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

As for your React app, if you're using create-react-app, then you can use [the `HOST` and `PORT` environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/). You can get your machine's local IP address using `ipconfig` on Windows, and on UNIX, use one of the methods described in https://superuser.com/q/347408/1749748 such as `ifconfig -a`. If you're not using create-react-app, then use the `host` and `port` fields of the `devServer` field of your Webpack config as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42083275/11107541).