# Exposing a React app in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm attempting to expose a react application to the Docker container it currently sits inside.

My Dockerfile successfully builds my image and runs my application on the configured port (8080). I then try to bind port 8080 of the container to port 8080 of the host. However, when I visit the host machine at port 8080 my application is not here.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name react-deployment-container react-deployment:dev
```

I have an existing node application already exposed on the same host machine running on a different port (3000), so I am confident it is not an issue binding a port when running the Docker container.

I think the issue might be the way I am attempting to expose the application in my Webpack configuration. Webpack builds perfectly but doesn't appear to available to the Docker container.

**webpack.config.js**

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080
  }
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
```

I have tinkered with the configuration recommended in the two questions below with no luck.

[How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ)

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/547

**The repo for this project is [here](https://github.com/EoinTraynor/react-game)**

Comment: Anything useful in "docker logs <containerId>"? Is the container running at all? Try "docker ps".

Comment: is your container up, check with "docker ps -a", if the container react-deployment-container is up then check the logs of the container by id with "docker logs <containerid>"

Comment: Can you go inside the container and use `curl localhost:8080`

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Yes. It prints the contents of the index file. So that makes me assume the container is running fine. Do I need to expose the application publicly i.e. not just localhost?

Comment: @JeffRSon Yes, the container is running and on port `8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080`.

Comment: Which OS are you using? And are you running docker inside a VM?

Comment: What about curl localhost:8080 from outside the docker container? Or the source view from browser? What does it mean "it's not there"?

Comment: @JeffRSon A curl request to localhost:8080 from the host machine (not inside the container) returns the contents of the index page. What I mean is that the application is not available on this port from the browser. I am only seeing an 'Invalid Host header' error message.

Comment: @JeffRSon @Tarun Lalwani @Jinna Balu Once I specified the public IP of my server it worked fine `--public 165.227.184.93:8080`.