# How to deploy react-native-web app into heroku?

Tags: heroku, react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-native-web

I am trying to use react-native-web in my college project.

I've following steps [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/) and successfully create a dev version of react-native-web app. I want to deploy my app onto Heroku, after searching many questions, I still can't run my app on Heroku. It always crashed after 60 seconds after starting.

```
2018-02-24T19:19:44.376383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --port 28330`
2018-02-24T19:19:49.667640+00:00 app[web.1]: Project is running at [1m[34mhttp://localhost:28330/[39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:19:49.668544+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack output is served from [1m[34m/[39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082843+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: [1m070ba25084e72482b7f3[39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082868+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack [1m3.11.0[39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082871+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: [1m11923[39m[22mms
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082873+00:00 app[web.1]:     [1mAsset[39m[22m     [1mSize[39m[22m  [1mChunks[39m[22m  [1m[39m[22m           [1m[39m[22m       [1mChunk Names[39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082874+00:00 app[web.1]: [1m[33mbundle.js[39m[22m  [1m[33m2.35 MB[39m[22m       [1m0[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  main
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082877+00:00 app[web.1]:    [2] [1m./node_modules/react/index.js[39m[22m 190 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082878+00:00 app[web.1]:   [65] [1m./node_modules/react-native-web/dist/index.js[39m[22m 12.9 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082880+00:00 app[web.1]:  [122] [1mmulti (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:28330 ./index.web.js[39m[22m 40 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082882+00:00 app[web.1]:  [123] [1m(webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:28330[39m[22m 7.91 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082884+00:00 app[web.1]:  [124] [1m./node_modules/url/url.js[39m[22m 23.3 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082885+00:00 app[web.1]:  [131] [1m./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js[39m[22m 161 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082887+00:00 app[web.1]:  [133] [1m./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js[39m[22m 7.86 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082889+00:00 app[web.1]:  [134] [1m(webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js[39m[22m 1.08 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082890+00:00 app[web.1]:  [136] [1m(webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js[39m[22m 3.67 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082892+00:00 app[web.1]:  [141] [1m(webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$[39m[22m 170 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082893+00:00 app[web.1]:  [143] [1m(webpack)/hot/emitter.js[39m[22m 77 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082895+00:00 app[web.1]:  [145] [1m./index.web.js[39m[22m 380 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082897+00:00 app[web.1]:  [243] [1m./node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/Vibration/index.js[39m[22m 796 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082899+00:00 app[web.1]:  [283] [1m./node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/VirtualizedList/index.js[39m[22m 327 bytes {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082901+00:00 app[web.1]:  [285] [1m./App.js[39m[22m 2.53 kB {[1m[33m0[39m[22m}[1m[32m [built][39m[22m
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082903+00:00 app[web.1]:     + 271 hidden modules
2018-02-24T19:20:02.082911+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2018-02-24T19:20:21.276101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-24T19:20:21.276101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-24T19:20:21.364850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-02-24T19:20:44.673361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-24T19:20:44.673652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-24T19:20:44.812657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-02-24T19:20:44.892098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Is there anyone who can show me the steps to deploy my react-native-web into Heroku?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Comment: I did, but I don't know where to put the code and how to run the code

Comment: You might need to create a server.js file with express framework or similar and serve your app with that and set the port to correct value. I'm not sure how because I have never used it but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ) and [this](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter/issues/57#issuecomment-306110573) posts might lead you somewhere

Comment: for reactjs there is a buildpack for heroku https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack , not sure if any for react native exists.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the webpack-dev-server in a production environment, which is not recommended.

You will need to:

1. Setup a production webpack build script in npm/yarn so that your browser side code gets built (usually output to a 'build' or 'dist' directory).  There should be instructions for on Heroku ([see here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)) so it knows which script to run to build this on the server after the server checks out your master branch.
2. Setup a minimal server script that is loaded via a 'start' script.  Try ExpressJs for this.  Note that Heroku creates a PORT environment variable (`process.env.PORT`) that contains the assigned HTTP port to use for the HTTP server (pass it to `express.listen`).  [Heroku have a minimal Express server example to look at](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started).