# docker react does not work in localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run my react app with docker, when I run the container, everything seems fine but I can't access it on localhost (or 127.0.0.1). Here is my configuration:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["npm", "run", "start-test"]
```

package.json

```
"start-test": "./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack.dev.config --inline --hot --history-api-fallback --port 8090 --public localhost:8090 --host 0.0.0.0"
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      // 'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'babel-polyfill',
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {...},
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      title: 'Production',
      // hash: true,
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [' ', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
```

webpack.config

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'app.css',
      disable: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

Everything is fine when I build by using

```
docker build --no-cache . -t seyaa/client
```

Then I start the container using

```
docker run  seyaa/client
```

Here is the end of the console

```
> redux-minimal@1.0.0 start-test /usr/src/app
> ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack.dev.config --inline --hot --history-api-fallback --port 8090 --public localhost:8090 --host 0.0.0.0

clean-webpack-plugin: /usr/src/app/dist has been removed.
Project is running at http://localhost:8090/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
Hash: 64fdd9746e89b58394d3
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 13617ms
```

The terminal looks fine but I can not access to http://localhost:8090 or http://127.0.0.1:8090 or http://0.0.0.0:8090

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: I am running on a mac

Comment: Check with ipconfig if docker created a bridge.  Find the pid of the docker with "ps -ef | grep docker", and check on what IP/Port docker is listening with "lsof -Pn -p PID | grep LISTEN".

Comment: when dealing with ports always mention what OS is your host running ... if linux issue this to see if port 8090 is active   `sudo  netstat -peanut`   .... other OS have similar tools

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here is the result of the comand

`ps -ef | grep docker
     501 29882   628   0  8:06pm ttys000    0:00.03 docker run seyaa/client
     501 29963 23000   0  8:08pm ttys004    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --
   exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg 
   --exclude-dir=.svn docker`

then when I do lsof -Pn -p 29963 | grep LISTEN  or with 23000, nothing happens. Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: It doesnt seem to be listening on 8090 for some reason .. :(

Comment: I must say, I don't see you starting seyaa/client.  So we see the "docker run" without a command to run, but the docker itself isn't running.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the output from your container, then you're listening on `localhost` *in the container*, which is not the same as *on the host*. Make the server listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` ([check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ)) then try hitting `localhost` on your host machine. You're also not exposing any ports through to your host by the looks of it, so you'll also need to change your `docker run` to be something like `docker run -p 8090:8090 seyaa/client`.

Comment: when you run `docker ps` you should see `0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp` in the PORTS column.

Answer (score 0):

A container must be started before you can run a command in it.

```
docker start seyaa/client
```

Then you may run eg. a shell

```
docker run seyaa/client /bin/sh
```