# Is there a way to let webpack dev server use another port?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

I'm using the webpack dev server, via the react scripts and I'd like to use the debugging functionality it offers via Visual Studio Code, however, I have a non-standard setup. We have service in front of the webpack dev server that proxies all requests, bundles requests with other services, handles security etc. So on local development, I open localhost:8080, which forwards all requests to localhost:8084 which is the webpack server. However, that service (on 8080) does not support websockets, and thus cannot forward them. I see webpack tries to fallback to an iFrame, which works for the reloading but not for debugging it seems.

Is there a way for me to explicitly tell webpack that it should connect to the webpack dev server on port 8084, instead of trying to do it via 8080? I already use I already use `PORT=8084 cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts start` in package.json, which I think passes on the port. However, the problem is that the socket is always opened to the same host/port you are running on. So when my page is proxied to `:8080`, tries the socket on `:8080` as well. What I want is to explicitly tell it not to use `8080`, but `8084`.

And secondary, it is correct that debugging doesn't work via the iFrame backup option?

Comment: What's exactly your problem for debugging? React-dev-tools not available on iframe mode? (In that case, check: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/57)

Comment: I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ) will help you

Answer (score 10):

You [can specify the port](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport) for webpack-dev-server on `webpack.config.js` or on the CLI.

> #### devServer.port
>
> `number`
>
> Specify a port number to listen for requests on:
>
> `webpack.config.js`
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   //...
>   devServer: {
>     port: 8080,
>   },
> };
> ```
>
> Usage via the CLI
>
> #### Webpack 4
>
> `webpack-dev-server --port 8080`
>
> #### Webpack 5
>
> `npx webpack serve --port 8080`