# I want to customize the port on which the output application runs. i don't want see the webpack-dev-server default info

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

[image] I want to customize the port on which the output application runs,instead of displaying the output information of "webpack dev server" by default. Who can help me or give me some suggestions

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to let webpack dev server use another port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402675/is-there-a-way-to-let-webpack-dev-server-use-another-port)

Comment: @Rashomon
Maybe I didn't describe the clearing. I don't want the console to output the information of webpack-dev-server initialization. I want to customize where the app runs on the console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add config to `webpack.config.js`

```js
infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'none',
}
```

Reference:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#level