# How to run webpack-dev-server on localhost without a port

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have a React app, to run it locally I use webpack-dev-server. This is how my command looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.js --open --https --hot --history-api-fallback",
  }
```

When I do `npm run dev-server` it opens a browser for me with url "https://localhost:8080/".

Is it possible to map it somehow to "https://localhost" (without the port)?

Comment: Please see the related thread for answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33272967/3679048

Comment: Actually I tried it. If I run it with the following. arguments: "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --open --https --hot --history-api-fallback" (as mentioned in that answer) the following URL is opened "https://0.0.0.0:80/" and I need to have the link "https://localhost" (for consistency purposes for my project)

Comment: Port 80 is default port it should be reachable via localhost itself, if I am not wrong.