# How can I use port 80 instead of 3000?

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app uses port 80, but heroku does not let my app access port 80. So, I used 3000 and ran it.

However, now, I cannot access it because port 3000 is not accessible in heroku. How can my app gain access to heroku?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think this is a misunderstanding regarding ports. Your app will run behind the proxy (aka load balancer), so you don't actually need to specify use `80` port (and you can't). Heroku provides env variable `PORT` and you **must** use that port to start your application. Heroku proxy runs on `80` port (and 443, which supports SSL) and redirect all traffic to `PORT` port.

> Your Node.js app is improperly configured to bind to a port other than the one provided by Heroku via the `$PORT` environment variable.

*Example:*

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

Ref: [Why is my Node.js app crashing with an R10 error?](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error)

Comment: well i created the env var and nothing

Comment: @RoboticObsession, you set `PORT`? That's not how this works. The `PORT` environment variable _will automatically be set **for you** by Heroku_. You just need to bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't.

Heroku doesn't allow you to assign listening ports to your web apps directly. Your web apps are self contained and they will be assigned a dynamic port by Heroku. The only way to access that is to use the default port (80).

Comment: so how can i use the port 80 in heroku and node.js?

Comment: You can use environment variable like this to make your app run on the port opened by heroku. 
```port = process.env.PORT || 80```

Comment: yes but heroku don't lets me acces that port

Comment: the error is toot much text so i will put the important thing
`Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`