# node: npm start: how to run on 0.0.0.0:3000

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a reactjs project made using create-react-app

In `nodejs` how to run `npm start` for `0.0.0.0:3000`

I tried

```
npm start --host 0.0.0.0:3000
```

But i am not able to connect from any ip

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
   ........
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the script you're running? Usually npm start points at something like `node index.js`

Comment: its a reactjs project

Comment: If it's a `create-react-app` project, npm start should be enough. You usually get an output of the IP(s) it's listening on. Can you share that?

Comment: what about HOST=0.0.0.0 npm start

Comment: I need to see some code to see what it's doing. HOST would be an env var, that I'd assume your project picks up.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project).

Comment: @Santhosh Please see marked duplicate. You'll need something like `"start": "export PORT=3000 react-scripts start"`

Comment: what about the ip, i am not able to access from external i

Comment: I am looking for more command line. so `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 npm start` - will it work

Comment: `HOST=123.456.789`. C'mon, Just google `create-react-app` `react-scripts ` change port/host. [How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ)

Comment: Anyway, change the port to an IP wouldn't make it a local dev-server. So consider checking thinks like firewalls.

Comment: Sorry , i found that its the firewall. `npm start` is itself sufficient. it allows the outside ips to connect also

Answer (score -1):

You can't just connect using CLI flags. You need to have files for example, to connect to port 3000 you'll need something like this:

```js
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.write('<h1>Hello, Node.js!</h1>');
    }
    res.end();
});

server.listen(3000)
```

this will create a web server listening to port `3000`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question OP asked.

Comment: It seems the question has been seriously modified since I posted this. This is not my fault