# React / Linux / How to configure webpack to run React on specific port?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my package.json :

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack serve  --hot --open",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production"
  },
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
```

I would like to run react on port 8017.

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ) in SO saying I should add these lines to my webpack :

```
devServer: {
    inline:true,
    port: 8017
  },
```

Does it mean I need to add a new line in my package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the proper parameter in your webpack.config.js. Have a look on the official documentation of webpack (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver). It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  devServer: {
  ...your custom devServer config,
  port: 8017,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```