# Can Not Set Environment Variable in NodeJS App-Windows

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am learning NodeJS and I need to know how to set my production environment using `process.env.___` .When I run

`console.log(app.get('env')); //app is express object`

I get output on command prompt `development` as environment. But if I try to set an environment variable
eg. `process.env.NODE_ENV`, on command prompt I write :`set NODE_ENV=production`and then again try : `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` I get output: `undefined`.
I've been struggling hard and searching online but have't got a solution yet.

Please, guide me in this matter.

Comment: I have the same issue with windows. Still could not find a solution for the. Hope this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529870/ifprocess-env-node-env-production-always-false

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy, I just dug a little and found that in poweshell type `$env:NODE_ENV="production"`. It did the work for me. Remember the dollar sign and quotes. Here is the source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Comment: Great..... you could answer your own question and that will help others too :)

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just dug a little and found that in poweshell type `$env:NODE_ENV="production"`. 
It did the work for me. Remember the dollar sign and quotes. 
Here is the source: [How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)