# Why after setting value to environment variable PORT the output is undefined?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, port

I am learning environment variable in Nodejs. I followed a tutorial video and wrote the exact same code in VS Code to set PORT value in the terminal. But for some reason, the output of PORT is undefined.

In editor, my code is like

```
//This is index.js file
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port ${port}...`)
})
```

In terminal, I typed `set PORT=2000` and pressed Enter.
In the next line of terminal, I typed `node index.js`.
The output in the terminal is `listening to port undefined`.

My OS is Windows. I tried solutions online, such as `PORT=2000 node index.js` and `SET PORT=2000 node index.js`. But none of them worked.

Comment: Which operating system are you using ? Is it windows if so your commands are perfect to set the env variables....If its mac/linux - export PORT=2000

Comment: I am using Windows OS. I don't understand why set PORT=2000 didn't work

Comment: I have found an answer on stackflow this afternoon. It worked in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945761/can-not-set-environment-variable-in-nodejs-app-windows

Answer (score 1):

These are different ways you can set the environment variables in node in different operating systems:

```
# Windows CMD:
SET PORT=2000
# or
set PORT=2000

# OS X / Linux:
export PORT=2000

# Windows PowerShell:
$env:PORT=2000
```