# How to disable generate "exports.__esModule = true;" and "require("lib");"

Tags: typescript

e.g:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js'></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.ts :

```
import { Vue } from "vue/types/vue";

let vue = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        text:"hello world"
    }
})
```

after cmd `tsc` it'll generate below js

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var vue_1 = require("vue/types/vue");
var vue = new vue_1.Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        text: "hello world"
    }
});
```

#### My Expected

I hope to disable generate "exports.__esModule = true;" and "require("lib");"

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        text: "hello world"
    }
});
```

#### PS:

I use [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) to get type definite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your **tsconfig.json** `module` to `es2015` and `moduleResolution` to `node`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

That is the [recommended configuration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Recommended-Configuration).

The `exports.__esModule` and `require('lib')` are what happen when we [transpile from an ES module to commonjs](http://2ality.com/2017/01/babel-esm-spec-mode.html) (with babel or with TypeScript).