# React 16.14.0: Error was not caught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I'm the author of [next-translate](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate/tree/1.0.0-experimental.8) library, and I'm working on an experimental version to which I get an **error with React 16.14.0** and I don't understand why it happens. **Upgrading React to version 17 then it works fine**, but I don't want to force everyone who uses the new version of my library to migrate their React version.

I've created a reproducible error example:
https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate-error-reproduction

In order to reproduce this issue:

- Clone this repo
- Run `yarn && yarn dev`
- Open `localhost:3000`
- Open devtools

`Error was not caught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

And the prerelease code of my lib is here:

- https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate/tree/1.0.0-experimental.14

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./lib/esm"
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

**tsconfig-cjs.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./lib/cjs",
    "declaration": false
  }
}
```

And this is the package code:

- https://www.runpkg.com/?next-translate@1.0.0-experimental.14

If anyone knows where this error came from and can help me I would be very grateful! I've been trying to solve it for several days but I'm a little lost because I don't know why it's happening... Thanks!

*Note: Looks that it only happens in development, doing `yarn build && yarn start` works fine.*

Comment: What is your version of Nodejs? I try to reproduce your step but it not throw any errors in devtool. My Node version is 12.19

Comment: I have Node v14.13.1

Comment: I tried to upgrade my Node to v14.13.1 and follow your steps again, but it did not show errors as you showed, I just see `{getStaticPropsWorks: true} Object {lang: ""}` in console. :(

Comment: I just tried again, doing clone + yarn + yarn dev, and I get the error... I don't think it's because of the OS, right? In my case, I have a Mac. I do not understand anything :/

Comment: @ThangLe by chance... you don't have a global version of TypeScript installed, do you?

Comment: Yes, I do not think it occurred by the OS. So you can visit this question here, and try to fix it with the top answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

Comment: By the way, I use Typescript latest version. So one more answer here you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497479/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-filed-generated-by-typescript/42510255. Hope all above can help you

Comment: I could reproduce the issue in Ubuntu 16 operation system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you've found the bug, here's the explanation of your case.

Let's compare the compiled result of both version:

Look around ln:54 in both files [1.0.0-experimental.14](https://www.runpkg.com/?next-translate@1.0.0-experimental.14/lib/cjs/appWithI18n.js#54)
[1.0.0-experimental.15](https://www.runpkg.com/?next-translate@1.0.0-experimental.15/lib/cjs/appWithI18n.js#54).

```js
var react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));

// The key different is the exclusion of this line:
var app_1 = __importDefault(require("next/app"));

var I18nProvider_1 = __importDefault(require("./I18nProvider"));
var loadNamespaces_1 = __importDefault(require("./loadNamespaces"));
```

Because you don't use `App.getInitialProps()` no more, the `import App from 'next/app'` is also dropped by TypeScript. The real problem lies in `next/app` module.

Following the breadcrumbs, we see `next/app` simple re-exports `next/dist/pages/_app`:

```js
module.exports = require('./dist/pages/_app')
```

As of the content of `./dist/pages/_app`, go check this [link](https://www.runpkg.com/?next@10.0.3/dist/pages/_app.js). It refs `exports` as a global variable everywhere, and that's causing the problem: `Error was not caught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

The problem is clear, that code of `next/dist/pages/_app.js` is included in the bundled JS code shipped to the webpage without being transpiled properly by webpack.

But after this point I cannot provide further help since I'm not familiar with the `next.js` stack. Guess you need to tune the webpack config to do something about that `exports` global variable.

Comment: Okay, I understand. next/app works well within the Next.js environment because it always passes through webpack, however if I want to use it from a third party library, as peerDependency, then it's not passing through webpack and does not solve this well. It's good to know! Thank you very much for taking the time to do this!

Answer (score 4):

I've already fixed it, but if I'm honest, I haven't understood why... Let's see if someone can explain it to me!

I was debugging and saw that it was something in my library code that caused TypeScript to compile badly. So, I was uncommenting line by line, until I saw what was wrong with the line:

```js
import App from 'next/app'

// Inside getInitialProps wrapper...
App.getInitialProps() // THIS LINE
```

It seems that when commenting `App.getInitialProps()` then TypeScript it compiles well. Fortunately, I have been able to dispense with this line of code in my library and now with prerelease [1.0.0-experimental.15](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate/releases/tag/1.0.0-experimental.15) it seems to work well with React 16.

I don't really understand why this could be happening, could it be because I have Next.js as peerDependency? I hope someone can clarify for me why this was happening

Comment: <3 EOL semicolons. They're worth keeping because if they waste your time like this even once, they can waste a ton of time.

Comment: Interesting case, where is that line? Can you post the link to source code location?