# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' express typescript

Tags: html, node.js, typescript, express

I'm using typescript to compile and run an express server that just serves an html file, but I keep getting this error in the response under the network tab in chrome for app.js: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Here's my server code:

```
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'

config()

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")))

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).send(err)
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})

const port = process.env.PORT
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Here's my folder structure:
[image: folder structure]

Here's my command for compiling and running the code:

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": "rimraf ./dist/ && tsc",
    "copy": "copyfiles -u 1 ./public/index.html ./dist",
    "start": "npm run compile && npm run copy && node dist"
  },
```

And here's my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>TypeScript</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I've done wrong? I'm pretty sure the file path is correct, but I've tried `./app.js` and removing the `defer` attribute from the `<script>` tag as well and I still get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part isn't necessary, because you have already served static files in "dist" folder. You need to remove it.

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).send(err)
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

It will send index.html for **all** incoming requests, including the request to get `app.js` file. That's why you have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`, '<' is the first character in the HTML file which is unexpected for a script.

Comment: When I removed that it throws an error: `Cannot GET /`. Are you saying remove this GET route entirely or just don't use `*` as a catchall?

Comment: Yes, I mean the route should be removed. I think this route isn't necessary because you have `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")))`. The error `Cannot GET / ` is unexpected for me. How about changing "*" to just "/" ? So it doesn't intercept the request to get the app.js file.

Comment: With just `/` I get this error in the console `GET http://localhost:3000/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I'm sure this line `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")))` does not do what it supposed to do because we cannot access static files... Can you try `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname)))` ?

Comment: Ok I made it just `__dirname` and now this error comes through in the console:
`app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at app.js:2`
The code in app.js:
`const test = "test" console.log(test) export default test`

Comment: So the file is loaded correctly :) Now it is the problem inside app.js. These links might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497479/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-filed-generated-by-typescript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined/43999062