# NextJS - `dev` not working but `build` && `start` do

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

Created a Next (version: `12.0.7`) with Typescript and Storybook. I can `build` and `start` the server, however, `dev` fails once I make a request and spits out this message:

Browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined
```

Backend:
No error message

I'm using Chakra UI, next-i18next and next-auth.

**Reproduce error**

1. Create a next app using typescript
   `npx create-next-app@latest --ts`
2. You will now face the error `exports is not defined`. Using [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497479/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-filed-generated-by-typescript/42510255) you can create a custom `_document.tsx` with this content:

```js
import Document, {
    Html,
    Head,
    Main,
    NextScript,
    DocumentContext,
} from "next/document"

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return {...initialProps}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head />
                <body>
                <Main />
                <script>var exports = {"{}"};</script>
                <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

3. Run `yarn run dev`
4. Visit http://localhost:3000/
5. See console

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for the hint, added a reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

FOUND THE TROUBLEMAKER!

When I opened the site in Chrome (which I personally don't use and so it doesn't have any extensions installed), the site worked flawlessly. After some digging, I found out that my Anti-Ad-Blocker was the troublemaker. Disabling it finally solved this error!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue where `next dev` would log:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /.../.env
event - compiled client and server successfully in 6.4s (2106 modules)
```

But when trying to access the site from Chrome or any other browser, nothing would happen, it would just get stuck loading forever.

It turns out the issue was cause by the VPN I was using (CyberGhost). After disabling it, everything worked again.