# typescript import create error after transpilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

for practice i created a simple TS project,

---

if it can help, there  my ts.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

my "project-tree" is very simple :

[image]

in the html i've imported the script in the -head- :

```
    <script defer type="module" src="./dist/index.js"></script>
```

the "classreminder.ts" :

```
export class ClassTestReminder {
  attribut: string;

  constructor(attribut: string) {
    this.attribut = attribut;
  }

  sayhello() {
    console.log(`hello ${this.attribut}`);
  }
}
```

Imported in the index.ts :

```
    import {ClassTestReminder} from "./class/classreminder";

     // other code...
     // form / input / button management
    
    const newObjectTest: ClassTestReminder = new ClassTestReminder("name");
    
    newObjectTest.sayhello();
```

---

Problem is, i end with the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/index.js:2
index.js:2:1
```

and the index.js do have this line 1 & 2 :

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I've tried multiple solution from here :
[Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined in filed generated by Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497479/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-filed-generated-by-typescript)

Saddly, nothing worked for me ( unless i forget some details that wasn't specified )

---

I've read somewhere to comment the  "module": "commonjs", from the ts.config.
Tried that and the js now have a "classic import" with this line 1

```
import {ClassTestReminder} from "./class/classreminder";
```

but the browser cast me another error like :"**module was blocked because of a disallowed mime type ( text/html )**"

tried different change with how i've imported the script, but still nothing work  ( *ofc if i comment the import so the class instance everything work, same if i create the class in the index.ts*)

Anyone know what i'am missing to have the import properly work ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

resolved my issue, well, sort of.

if i comment

```
//"module": "commonjs",
```

which so far i understand make the ts transpile in  ES6 and not in ES5 anymore ( *which is why the import in js remain the same as how you declare them usualy* )

and add a .js at the end of every import in the TS files ( yes in the TS files ) to have something like :

```
 import {ClassTestReminder} from "./class/classreminder.js";
```

This way there is no issue with TS / import and so with the project and "liveserver" in browser
But.. since the "module": "commonjs", is commented, i cant run the project in the terminal anymore...

If anyone have a better alternative i would be interested.

thanks.