# Node Environmental variable on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I noticed this strange behavior which is not a big deal, but bugging the heck out of me.

In my package.json file, under the "scripts" section, I have a "start" entry. It looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "APPLICATION_ENV=development nodemon app.js"
}
```

typing `npm start` on a Mac terminal works fine, and nodemon runs the app with the correct APPLICATION_ENV variable as expected. When I try the same on a Windows environment, I get the following error:

"'APPLICATION_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have tried the git-bash shell and the normal Win CMD prompt, same deal.

I find this odd, because typing the command directly into the terminal (not going through the package.json script via npm start) works fine.

Has anyone else seen this and found a solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

For cross-platform usage of environment variables in your scripts install and utilize [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env APPLICATION_ENV=development nodemon app.js"
}
```

The issue is explained well at the link provided to `cross-env`. It reads:

> Most Windows command prompts will choke when you set environment variables with `NODE_ENV=production` like that. (The exception is Bash on Windows, which uses native Bash.) Similarly, there's a difference in how windows and POSIX commands utilize environment variables. With POSIX, you use: `$ENV_VAR` and on windows you use `%ENV_VAR%`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package based on the 2nd answer here:

[Node.js: Setting Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/node-js-setting-environment-variables)

I like this because it allows me to setup environmental variables without having to inject extra text into my npm script lines. Instead, they are using a .env file (which should be placed on each environment and ommitted from version control).

Answer (score 0):

You should use "set" command to set environment variables in Windows.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set APPLICATION_ENV=development && nodemon app.js"
}
```

Something like this.