# NPM "build" not working for my react + webpack project

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I am trying to run npm build on an old project I worked on months ago. It worked before after I ran

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Now I have formatted my machine but  still getting this error

> ```
> 'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

Here is my package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --mode development --config webpack.config.js",
  "preview": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --mode production --config webpack.config.js",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js"
}
```

This scrip worked before but now I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Any reasonable suggestion would be great!

FYI, I am using a Windows machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NODE\_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman)

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#windows-cmdexe

Comment: None of these worked for me

Comment: Consider installing [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) in your project. Then add the `cross-env` keyword at the beginning of each of your npm scripts. For example, your `build` scripts would be redefined as: `"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Environmental variable on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164458/node-environmental-variable-on-windows)