# reactstrap typescript nx `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reactstrap, nrwl

I'm using `reactstrap@8.6.0` with nx and typescript. But if any component is included from reactstrap the app is crashing with below error

```
index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object.../../../node_modules/has-symbols/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../../node_modules/get-intrinsic/index.js (index.js:54)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../../node_modules/call-bind/callBound.js (callBound.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../../node_modules/is-arguments/index.js (index.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../../node_modules/deep-equal/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175521/referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-at-eval#answer-45186498) tried below configuration in `jest.config.js` but avail no luck.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'cadence',
  preset: '../../jest.config.js',
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': [
      'babel-jest',
      { cwd: __dirname, configFile: './babel-jest.config.json' },
    ],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/cadence',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  target: 'node',
  node: { global: true },
};
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Tried placing `<script>const global = globalThis;</script>` in `index.html` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586906/react-and-electron-with-draft-js-global-is-not-defined#answer-67336441) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved by modifying webpack config - Add webpack.config.js to *apps/your-react-app/webpack.config.js* with:

```
const nrwlConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
    nrwlConfig(config);

    return {
        ...config,
        node: {
            global: true,
        },
    };
};
```