# Node JS to load dotenv with forever

Tags: node.js, express, forever

I would like to ask if anyone know how to run forever that can load .env file.

Currently if we run `forever start app.js`, process.env.foo become undefined.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR, You need to add the `--workingDir` path to your cronjob line.

```
forever -c "node -r dotenv/config" --workingDir app-workdir-path start app.js
```

---

Many previous answers but none of them really solve this specific use case.

To run [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) you'll need to do two things.

First is we need to use dotenv's [preload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#preload) feature, meaning we need forever to pass a node parameter to the process. we can do it by using the `-c  COMMAND` flag forever has.

The second thing is related to how the `dotenv` package works. here is snippet from the source code:

```
let dotenvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')
```

What does `process.cwd()` do?

> The process.cwd() method is an inbuilt application programming interface of the process module which is used to get the current working directory of the node.js process.

Meaning `dovenv` package want's to load the `.env` file from the working directory. so to solve this issue we can use forever's `--workingDir` flag to specify the actual working directory of the process.

And the final command will look like this:

```
forever -c "node -r dotenv/config" --workingDir app-workdir-path start app.js
```

Where `app-workdir-path` is the absolute path to the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to specify the full path:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/opt/api/.env' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package for this purpose. On your app entry, do this

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' })
```

Comment: i have tried this, but still the same result. all the variable inside .env become undefined.

Comment: .env file is in the same folder level as app entry?

Comment: yes, it is. im not sure it is because forever js or others.

Comment: As of 1/14/2018, this didn't work for me when using forever. I posted a work around below. I believe it has to do with forever's path not picking up environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `.env` file in root directory of your project then you can use like this
`require('dotenv').config()`

Or if you created your file `.env` with different location then in your code use
`require('dotenv').config({path : '/your/path/.env'})`

Answer (score 0):

I found your question and had the same issue. I don't think `dotenv` works with forever - At least not that I was able to get working. However, I think there's a workaround that you could employ. I was able to specify environment variables on the command line preceding the forever command, and forever passed those environment variables to my node app.

`~$ ENV=production forever start yourApp.js`

For more information about specifying environment variables on the command line, checkout this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/setting-environment-variables-for-node-to-retrieve).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with multiserver forever config.

You should include `--workingDir` parameter pointing to the root of your project directory in case you've included `.env` file in your root and using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Example:

- Flexible config with minimum "hard coded" values
- `.env` placed in root directory
- "dotenv" used in form of `dotenv.config()`

Code for multiserver config in case of one server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let foreverConfig = [
  {
    uid: 'scheduledJobsServer',
    append: true,
    watch: true,
    script: 'scheduledJobsServer.js',
    sourceDir: path.join(__dirname, '/server'),
    workingDir: path.join(__dirname)
  },
  {
    uid: 'mainServer',
    append: true,
    watch: true,
    script: 'server.js',
    sourceDir: path.join(__dirname, '/server'),
    workingDir: path.join(__dirname)
  }
];

try {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, '/foreverConfig.json'),
    JSON.stringify(foreverConfig),
    { encoding: 'utf8' }
  );
  let consoleMessage = 'Init script success';
  console.log('\x1b[42m%s\x1b[0m', consoleMessage);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Init script error:', e);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Then run `forever start foreverConfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to call the node script from another directory. For instance, when running cron jobs. Here is what you can do:

```
cd /path/to/script/ && /usr/bin/forever start /usr/bin/node script.js
```

Now the .env file will load.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest command for me is

```sh
dotenv -e .env forever start build/index.js
```