# WebdriverJS - How to create Chrome environment variable programmaticaly and use it in the code

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In WebdriverJS is there anyway to create environment variable programmaticaly and use that variable in my code. I want to store the JSON response in the environment variable and assert the data in the environment variable against expected result.

Comment: Please provide more details. whats the expected result and json response that you are getting? why you need it?

Comment: In my application I run a search that triggers REST service and returns multiple results in the form of JSON. I want to validate that each response contains the word I searched for. I see the response using Chrome's developer tool and manually I can create environment variable and query for the expected result. However, thousands of words that I need to search for. So I need to automate this. One way to test this is by testing the API itself through Postman. But we are expected to test this through UI so need some solution in WebdriverJS.

Comment: This might be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/node-js-setting-environment-variables

Comment: @Zeus : given your requirement you should hit the API call and compare the response to what you get on UI after search.

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra: Problem with making API call is that everytime I make a API call we get separate records. Which is by design. So I cannot compare the result with API. Hence, was looking for a way to compare it with response that I see in Chrome Developer tool.