# how to set and get environment variable in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set and get environment variable in node js .I tried like this
I create the `test.js` file
And add this line

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Run like this

```
 set NODE_ENV=production&&node test.js
```

**It gives me undefined**

Comment: u can read this article https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786 
hope it will help

Comment: Try `NODE_ENV=production node test.js`

Comment: `set` creates shell variables, not environment variables.

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Comment: You have to do EXPORT NODE_ENV instead of SET NODE_ENV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NODE_ENV=production node test.js` on linux and `$env:NODE_ENV = 'production'; node test.js` in powershell.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer:

From nodejs docs

> It is possible to modify this object, but such modifications will not be reflected outside the Node.js process.

So you can also do something like:

```
process.env.foo = 'bar';
console.log(process.env.foo);
```

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

```
process.env.test = null;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 'null'
```

Note: There are some `env` variables which you can set only before any codes are executed.

Also note:

> On Windows operating systems, environment variables are case-insensitive.

```
process.env.TEST = 1;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. create a package.json file.
2. install the dotenv npm package

make a .env file in your root directory. 
//env 
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8626
# Set your database/API connection information here
API_KEY=**************************
API_URL=**************************
```

Now if you want to call your port in any file or server.js it will be like this.

```
const port = process.env.PORT;
console.log(`Your port is ${port}`);
```