# NodeJS: Use Data in Raw Format from .env

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, jimp

I have the following code which uses `Jimp` package to edit the background of a file:

```js
const file = await Jimp.read(JPGPath)
  file
    .resize(parseInt(width), parseInt(height))
    .background(process.env.JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    .write(JPGPath)
```

Anytime I run this code, I get an error from `Jimp` saying: `Error: hex must be a hexadecimal rgba value"`

The value of `JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR` in `.env` is `0xFFFFFFFF` which is a correct hexadecimal rgba value for `Jimp`

So the code works whenever i use the `JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR` value directly like this:

```js
const file = await Jimp.read(JPGPath)
  file
    .resize(parseInt(width), parseInt(height))
    .background(0xFFFFFFFF)
    .write(JPGPath)
```

How can I make the first code to work because i need to set the `JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR` in `.env`

Note: `console.log(process.env.JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR)` prints `0xFFFFFFFF` so the value is not empty, but it is parsed to string whereas `Jimp` doesn't accept strings so how do i pass the value from `.env` raw into the `Jimp` package

Comment: please check if your env variable has value by printing it, i think you env variables are not loading.

Comment: There is a really usefull package `dotenv`: it parses a .env file and stores the values in `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: @israel-obanijesu [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/setting-environment-variables-for-node-to-retrieve) should help

Comment: It is loading @salman and Hollyol, i already printed it, but the problem is the data format is in string, it needs to be raw not string

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load variables from .env file.

As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

it will be enough for you.
updated:

please use parseInt

```
file
    .resize(parseInt(width), parseInt(height))
    .background(parseInt(process.env.JPG_BACKGROUND_COLOR))
    .write(JPGPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

load dot env file package and then import it