# How to get env variables to be recognized when running nodejs CLI globally

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I made a simple nodejs CLI using commander to send API requests. I am on Windows. I want to run the CLI from anywhere by calling the app name without having to type node.js. I was able to do this using `npm link`. I am using `dotenv` for environment variables where I store the API key. However, it looks like the app only picks up the variables from my .env file when I run the app from within the app folder. I am able to run the app from anywhere, but when I use a CLI command that calls a function that accesses the .env file, I get an `undefedined TypeError`. It only works if I run this command from within the app folder. Is there a way I can get this to work where I don't need to be in the app folder and can run CLI commands that access the .env file?

Comment: Hi, dotenv will load your variables on startup: this means that the variables are available only within process.env object that provides information about *the current Node.js process*. How do you access the .env file? Because you will have all the env variables within process.env object

Comment: The file is accessed as you suggest `process.env.KEY`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69192183/14998487 This might help